# Tips for golfing in Python

Tags: code-golf, python, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in Python? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Python (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: Use Python 2 for golfing not 3

Comment: @Chris_Rands That simply does not universally hold, as there are cases in which Python 3 allows for shorter submissions.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Especially the new `:=` operator in 3.8

Comment: Related: [code golf - Tips for golfing with numpy, scipy, or pylab - Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156599/tips-for-golfing-with-numpy-scipy-or-pylab)

Answer (score 212):

Use `a=b=c=0` instead of `a,b,c=0,0,0`. (Note that this uses the same instance for each variable, so don't do this with objects like lists if you intend to mutate them independently)

Use `a,b,c='123'` instead of `a,b,c='1','2','3'`.

Comment: that's nice tip in general :)

Comment: Note that this will not necessarily work for defining mutable objects that you will be modifying in-place. a=b=[1] is actually different from a=[1];b=[1]

Comment: The funny thing about the first tip is that it works in Java too.

Comment: @Justin Yes, but only with primitive types

Comment: But NEVER use a=b=c=[] or any object instanciation since all the variables will point to the same instance. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: First part bad, second part good. a, b, and c will all refer to the same thing; changing one will change them all!

Answer (score 200):

Conditionals can be lengthy. In some cases, you can replace a simple conditional with `(a,b)[condition]`. If `condition` is true, then `b` is returned.

Compare

```python
if a<b:return a
else:return b
```

To this

```python
return(b,a)[a<b]
```

Comment: These aren't exactly the same. The first one evaluates only the expression that is returned while the second one always evaluates them both. These ones do short-circuit: `a if a<b else b` and `a<b and a or b`

Comment: `(lambda(): b, lambda(): a)[a < b]()` make your own short-circuit with lambdas

Comment: @marinus, they are not equal: just consider `P and A or B` for any A that gives `bool(A)=False`. But `(P and [A] or [B])[0]` will do the job.
See http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html for reference.

Comment: Lambdas are way longer than a conditional expression.

Comment: @user2357112 But they make you look so much cooler when you use them. :]

Comment: Be careful of using this to do recursion, ie. `f = lambda a:(a, f(a-1))[a>1]` because this will evaluate the options *before* the conditional, unlike `f = lambda a: f(a-1) if a>1 else a`, which only executes the recursive `f(a-1)` if the condition `a>1` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Of course, in this particular case, it can be golfed further to 'return min(a,b)'

Comment: Also useful inside of list comprehensions e.g. `[("odd","even")[i%2] for i in range(10)]` compared to `["odd"if i%2 else"even" for i in range(10)]`

Comment: If you swap the even and odd you can make it even shorter with this monstrosity: `["eovdedn"[i%2::2]for i in range(10)]`

Answer (score 158):

A great thing I did once is:

```python
if 3 > a > 1 < b < 5: foo()
```

instead of:

```python
if a > 1 and b > 1 and 3 > a and 5 > b: foo()
```

Python’s comparison operators rock.

---

Using that everything is comparable in Python 2, you can also avoid the `and` operator this way. For example, if `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are integers,

```python
if a<b and c>d:foo()
```

can be shortened by one character to:

```python
if a<b<[]>c>d:foo()
```

This uses that every list is larger than any integer.

If `c` and `d` are lists, this gets even better:

```python
if a<b<c>d:foo()
```

Comment: Of course if this were actually golfed it'd be `3>a>1<b<5`

Comment: Love the symmetry. Reminds me of the old Perl golf trick for finding the min of $a and $b: `[$a => $b]->[$b <= $a]` :)

Comment: Note that the second example (no lists) can also be done with `if(a<b)+(c>d):foo()`

Comment: The + should be a `*`. An `or` would be `+`

Comment: Perl 6 allows it too

Comment: `foo()if 3>a>1<b<5`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `foo()if 3>a>1<b<5` doesn't work for me.

Comment: A note: The whole "every list is larger than any integer" rule is only a thing on Python 2, so you can't use that trick on Python 3 (which has stricter typing for comparisons).

Answer (score 132):

If you're using a built-in function repeatedly, it might be more space-efficient to give it a new name, if using different arguments:

```
r=range
for x in r(10):
 for y in r(100):print x,y
```

Comment: Didn't actually save any bytes, though.

Comment: r=range and the other two r's are 9 characters; using range twice is 10 characters.  Not a huge saving in this example but all it would take is one more use of range to see a significant saving.

Comment: @Frank The additional newline is another character.

Comment: Indeed two repetitions is too little to save on a length five function name. You need: length 2: 6 reps, length 3: 4 reps, length 4 or 5: 3 reps, length >=6: 2 reps. AKA (length-1)*(reps-1)>4.

Comment: Note this is applicable to all languages with first-class functions.

Comment: Dosent work for `split()` function :/

Comment: @DollarAkshay why ?!?

Comment: @Programmer it's not a function, it's a method on strings.

Comment: @DollarAkshay It works for `str.split` though.

Answer (score 126):

Use string substitution and `exec` to deal with long keywords like `lambda` that are repeated often in your code.

```python
a=lambda b:lambda c:lambda d:lambda e:lambda f:0   # 48 bytes  (plain)
exec"a=`b:`c:`d:`e:`f:0".replace('`','lambda ')    # 47 bytes  (replace)
exec"a=%sb:%sc:%sd:%se:%sf:0"%(('lambda ',)*5)     # 46 bytes  (%)
```

The target string is very often `'lambda '`, which is 7 bytes long. Suppose your code snippet contains `n` occurences of `'lambda '`, and is `s` bytes long. Then:

- The `plain` option is `s` bytes long.
- The `replace` option is `s - 6n + 29` bytes long.
- The `%` option is `s - 5n + 22 + len(str(n))` bytes long.

From a [plot of *bytes saved over `plain`*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSeF2.png) for these three options, we can see that:

- For *n < 5* lambdas, you're better off not doing anything fancy at all.
- For *n = 5*, writing `exec"..."%(('lambda ',)*5)` saves 2 bytes, and is your best option.
- For *n > 5*, writing `` exec"...".replace('`','lambda ') `` is your best option.

**For other cases, you can index the table below:**

```
          1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 (occurences)
       +---------------------------------------------------------
     3 |  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  r  r  r  r  r  
     4 |  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
     5 |  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
     6 |  -  -  -  -  -  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
     7 |  -  -  -  -  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
     8 |  -  -  -  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
     9 |  -  -  -  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
    10 |  -  -  %  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
    11 |  -  -  %  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
    12 |  -  -  %  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r   r = replace
    13 |  -  -  %  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r   % = string %
    14 |  -  %  %  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r   - = do nothing
    15 |  -  %  %  %  %  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  
  (length)
```

For example, if the string `lambda x,y:` (length 11) occurs 3 times in your code, you're better off writing `exec"..."%(('lambda x,y:',)*3)`.

Comment: this should get more votes, it's a very useful tip.

Comment: it's *extremely* rare that this works.  the cost of `replace` is huge.

Comment: When it does work, though, it helps a lot.

Comment: Interesting, never even tghought of this!

Comment: I added a new operator for lambda in my language based off of python: `=>` is just the string `= lambda `. For example, `f=>:0` would be `f = lambda: 0`.

Comment: The same applies to `import` - you can do `for s in ('module1','module2','etc'):exec"from %s import*"%s`

Comment: If you use this often enough for `.replace("R",'.replace("')` to save bytes, many other replacements become cheaper. (It also makes your code entirely unreadable.)

Answer (score 122):

Sometimes your Python code requires you to have 2 levels of indentation. The obvious thing to do is use one and two spaces for each indentation level.

However, Python 2 considers the tab and space characters to be different indenting levels.

This means the first indentation level can be one space and the second can be one tab character.

For example:

```
if 1:
 if 1:
	pass
```

Comment: Cool, I never thought about this one!

Comment: This fails in python3: you can no more mix spaces and tabs(a bad thing for codegolf, but a good thing in all other cases).

Comment: In python 3.4 this seems to work fine.

Comment: [@trichoplax](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20283/trichoplax), In python 3.4.3 I get `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.`

Comment: For reference, a tab is worth 8 spaces.

Comment: Note that your editor *may* be changing the tab characters into space. This happened to me in VSCode. The trick there is to 1) enable whitespace rendering - `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` and 2) stop the editor from replacing it with whitespace - `"editor.insertSpaces": false, "editor.detectIndentation": false`. (VSCode version 1.46.1). If you want these to work only for the current golfing project, you can add a local settings.json file to the current workspace.

Answer (score 106):

### Store lookup tables as magic numbers

Say you want to hardcode a Boolean lookup table, like which of the first twelve English numbers contain an `n`.

```python
0: False
1: True
2: False
3: False
4: False
5: False
6: False
7: True
8: False
9: True
10:True
11:True
12:False
```

Then, you can implement this lookup table concisely as:

```python
3714>>i&1
```

with the resulting `0` or `1` being equal to `False` to `True`.

The idea is that the magic number stores the table as a bitstring `bin(3714)` = `0b111010000010`, with the `n`-th digit (from the end) corresponding the the `n`th table entry. We access the `n`th entry by bitshifting the number `n` spaces to the right and taking the last digit by `&1`.

This storage method is very efficient. Compare to the alternatives

```python
n in[1,7,9,10,11]
'0111010000010'[n]>'0'
```

You can have your lookup table store multibit entries that can be extracted like

```python
 340954054>>4*n&15
```

to extract the relevant four-bit block.

Comment: Could we have an example result for the four-bit block? Did you use a rule for n-bit block?

Comment: Hex might sometimes be even smaller.

Comment: This is useful for a lot of languages.

Comment: @Joonazan Hex is smaller for numbers over [999 999](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: `n in [...]` might be smaller for sparse sets.

Answer (score 104):

Use extended slicing to select one string from many

```python
>>> for x in 0,1,2:print"fbboaaorz"[x::3]
... 
foo
bar
baz
```

vs

```python
>>> for x in 0,1,2:print["foo","bar","baz"][x]
... 
foo
bar
baz
```

In this Boolean two-string case, one can also write

```python
b*"string"or"other_string"
```

for

```python
["other_string","string"][b]
```

Unlike interleaving, this works for strings of any length, but can have operator precedence issues if `b` is instead an expression.

Comment: Note that the first example is exactly the same length as `for x in ("foo","bar","baz"): print x`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, That's just an example of how the different values of `x` are rendered. The golfed part is the `"fbboaaorz"[x::3]` vs `["foo","bar","baz"][x]` How the `x` value is derived would be another part of your golf solution.

Answer (score 96):

### Collapse two numerical loops into one

Say you're iterating over the cells of an `m*n` grid. Instead of two nested `for` loops, one for the rows and one for the columns, it's usually shorter to write a single loop to iterate over the `m*n` cells of the grid. You can extract the row and column of the cell inside the loop.

**Original code:**

```python
for i in range(m):
 for j in range(n):
  do_stuff(i,j)
```

**Golfed code:**

```python
for k in range(m*n):
 do_stuff(k/n,k%n)
```

In effect, you're iterating over the Cartesian product of the two ranges, encoding the pair `(i,j)` as `x=i*n+j`. You've save a costly `range` call and a level of indentation inside the loop. The order of iteration is unchanged.

Use `//` instead of `/` in Python 3. If you refer to `i` and `j` many times, it may be shorter to assign their values `i=k/n`, `j=k%n` inside the loop.

Comment: This is awesome. I had never realised this was possible!

Comment: I saw this in the tips for JavaScript. It's a pretty useful trick in most languages.

Comment: For reference, to extend this to 3 loops: `for i in range(m*n*o): do_stuff(i/n/o,i%(n*o)/o,i%o)`

Comment: For `n` loops: https://repl.it/EHwa

Comment: In some cases, `itertools.product` can be much more concise than nested loops, especially when generating cartesian products. `a1, a2, b1, b2` are examples of the cartesian product of `'ab'` and `'12'`

Comment: in GLSL it is basically free ( no need to store the result ) because loop are unrolled at compilation and all these computation collapsed.

Answer (score 91):

Use `` `n` `` to convert an integer to a string instead of using `str(n)`:

```python
>>> n=123
>>> `n`
'123'
```

Note: Only works in Python 2.

Comment: Attention: really works for integers, but not for strings, for example.

Comment: btw. `` is short for repr

Comment: Integers smaller than -2\*\*31 or bigger than 2\*\*31-1 (Longs) gets an 'L' tacked on at the end.

Comment: This can also be used to print floats to full precision

Answer (score 83):

For integer `n`, you can write

- `n+1` as `-~n`
- `n-1` as  `~-n`

because the bit flip `~x` equals `-1-x`. This uses the same number of characters, but can indirectly cut spaces or parens for operator precedence.

Compare:

```python
while n-1:  #Same as while n!=1 
while~-n:

c/(n-1)
c/~-n

or f(n)+1
or-~f(n) 

(n-1)/10+(n-1)%10
~-n/10+~-n%10
```

The operators `~` and unary `-` are higher precedence than `*`, `/`, `%`, unlike binary `+`.

Comment: A variation on this trick I ran into today: `-~-x` saves one byte vs. `(1-x)`.

Comment: Another useful application is that `a+b+1` can be more concisely written as `a-~b`.

Comment: And `n-i-1` is just `n+~i`.

Answer (score 77):

Unless the following token starts with `e` or `E`. You can remove the space following a number.

For instance:

```
if i==4 and j==4:
    pass
```

Becomes:

```
if i==4and j==4:
    pass
```

Using this in complicated one line statements can save quite a few characters.

EDIT: as @marcog pointed out, `4or a` will work, but not `a or4` as this gets confused with a variable name.

Comment: `if(i,j)==(4,4):` is even shorter and in this special case `if i==j==4:`

Comment: Related: `4or a` works, but not `a or4`

Comment: `0or` also doesn't work (`0o` is a prefix for octal numbers).

Comment: @Nabb Not that it matters anyways, since `0 or x` is always gonna return `x`. Might as well cut out the `0 or`.

Comment: `0or` is fine as part of a longer number though. `10 or x` is equivalent to `10or x`.

Comment: If you end a variable name with a number, can you put a variable at the front?

Comment: @theonlygusti No.

Answer (score 73):

A nice way to convert an iterable to list on **Python 3**:

imagine you have some iterable, like

```
i = (1,2,3,4)
i = range(4)
i = (x**2 for x in range(5))
```

But you need a list:

```
x=list(i)  #the default way
*x,=i      #using starred assignment -> 4 char fewer
```

It's very useful to make a list of chars out of a string

```
s=['a','b','c','d','e']
s=list('abcde')
*s,='abcde'
```

Comment: typing `*s,='abcde'` and then `s` crashes my interactive python3 with a segfault :(

Comment: My Python 3.5 works fine.

Comment: for i = (x**2 for x in range(5)) I get this code returned <generator object <genexpr> at 0x03321690>

Comment: @george Now try `*x,=i` ...

Comment: @JBernardo thanks!

Comment: And if you're doing this in an expression, you can do `[*'abcde']`.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit No you can't. `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`

Comment: @Jakob You might be using an older version of Python, because it only works as of [version 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Comment: Oh, cool! Yeah, I was on 3.4.

Comment: `i = [x**2 for x in range(5)]`

Answer (score 67):

## [Extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) ("Starred assignment", Python 3 only)

The best way to explain this is via an example:

```python
>>> a,*b,c=range(5)
>>> a
0
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c
4
```

We've already seen a use for this — [turning an iterable into a list in Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4389/21487):

```python
a=list(range(10))
*a,=range(10)
```

Here are a few more uses.

### Getting the last element from a list

```python
a=L[-1]
*_,a=L
```

In some situations, this can also be used for getting the first element to save on parens:

```python
a=(L+[1])[0]
a,*_=L+[1]
```

### Assigning an empty list and other variables

```python
a=1;b=2;c=[]
a,b,*c=1,2
```

### Removing the first or last element of a non-empty list

```python
_,*L=L
*L,_=L
```

These are shorter than the alternatives `L=L[1:]` and `L.pop()`. The result can also be saved to a different list.

*Tips courtesy of @grc*

Comment: Wow! I have written `a=1;L=[]` so many times. It's amazing that you can save chars on something so straightforward as this.

Comment: @xnor That one's thanks to grc. With only one other element it's not as good (`a,*L=1,`), but it still saves one char :)

Comment: don't forget you can also get both the first and last element of a list with `a,*_,b=L`

Answer (score 64):

Instead of `range(x)`, you can use the `*` operator on a list of anything, if you don't actually need to use the value of `i`:

```
for i in[1]*8:pass
```

as opposed to

```
for i in range(8):pass
```

If you need to do this more than twice, you could assign any iterable to a variable, and multiply that variable by the range you want:

```
r=1,
for i in r*8:pass
for i in r*1000:pass
```

**Note**: this is often longer than `exec"pass;"*8`, so this trick should only be used when that isn't an option.

Comment: @proudhaskeller I think the point of the line you removed was that "In addition to the obvious character savings you get because `[1]*8` is shorter than `range(8)`, you also get to save a space because `for i in[...` is legal while `for i in range...` is not".

Comment: oh, right, i didn't understand that. fixed now

Comment: @MorganThrapp how does that save bytes over `for i in[1]*8:pass`?

Comment: `exec"pass;"*8` is significantly shorter.

Comment: If this is being used in a list comprehension, this can be used to loop with a variable. Useful in `lambda`s. What I'm saying is instead of `for i in[1]*n:a=(expression);`, you do `for a in[expression]*n:`

Comment: if `r=1`, `r*8` is 8, and you can't iterate through a number. I guess you meant `r=[1]`

Comment: @ArtemisFowl, no it's ok as is, the comma after the 1 creates a tuple which is iterable.

Comment: @sasha True, I should've tested it.

Answer (score 64):

You can use the good old alien smiley face to reverse sequences:

```python
[1, 2, 3, 4][::-1] # => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 52):

### Use ~ to index from the back of a list

If `L` is a list, use `L[~i]` to get the `i`'th element from the back.

This is the `i`'th element of the reverse of `L`. The bit complement `~i` equals `-i-1`, and so fixes the off-by-one error from `L[-i]`.

Comment: Woah, that's so good I wanna use it in real code

Answer (score 51):

For ages it bothered me that I couldn't think of a short way to get the entire alphabet. If you use `range` enough that `R=range` is worth having in your program, then

```
[chr(i+97)for i in R(26)]
```

is shorter than the naive

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

, but otherwise it's longer by a single character. It haunted me that the clever one that required some knowledge of ascii values ended up being more verbose than just typing all the letters.

Until I saw [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25627/14509) answer for [My Daughter's Alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25625/my-daughters-alphabet). I can't follow the edit history well enough to figure out if this genius was the work of the OP or if it was a suggestion by a commenter, but this is (I believe) the shortest way to create an iterable of the 26 letters in the Roman alphabet.

```
map(chr,range(97,123))
```

If case doesn't matter, you can strip off another character by using uppercase:

```
map(chr,range(65,91))
```

I use `map` way too much, I don't know how this never occurred to me.

Comment: Might use this in actual coding, I feel so stupid when hardcoding these things :')

Comment: In actual coding, use `string.lowercase` -- that's what it's there for.

Comment: if you need both cases, the shortest way I know is filter(str.isalpha,map(chr,range(256))). It's just barely shorter than s=map(chr,range(256));s+=map(str.lower,s)

Comment: @quintopia: Why 256 instead of 122 (`ord('z')`)? Aside from it being the same length... Also, if you need alphanumerics, replace `str.isalpha` in @quintopia's version with `str.isalnum`. (But if you only need one case, the whole 36-character string is no longer than `filter(str.isalnum,map(chr,range(90)))`.)

Comment: @TimPederick using 256 saves having to look up or remember what `ord('z')` is ;-) Also, I've learned that `import string;string.ascii_letters` is actually shorter if you don't mind the lowercase coming before the uppercase letters.

Comment: If you going to be unfair and use range as `R`, my version is shorter than your original one: `'%c'*26%tuple(R(97,123))` (only 24 chars) if you spell `range` it is just as long as the alphabet -- uppercase version is shorter

Answer (score 47):

### set literals in Python2.7

You can write sets like this `S={1,2,3}` This also means you can check for membership using `{e}&S` instead of `e in S` which saves one character.

Comment: And this also saves the character in `if`s as there is no spaces (`if{e}&S:`)

Comment: Note that you can replace `not in` by `{e}-S` with that trick

Answer (score 46):

**Choosing one of two numbers based on a condition**

You [already know](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62/20260) to use the list selection `[x,y][b]` with a Boolean `b` for the ternary expression `y if b else x`. The variables `x`, `y`, and `b` can also be expressions, though note that both `x` and `y` are evaluated even when not selected.

Here's some potential optimizations when `x` and `y` are numbers.

- `[0,y][b] -> y*b`
- `[1,y][b] -> y**b`
- `[x,1][b] -> b or x`
- `[x,x+1][b] -> x+b`
- `[x,x-1][b] -> x-b`
- `[1,-1][b] -> 1|-b`
- `[x,~x][b] -> x^-b`
- `[x,y][b] -> x+z*b` (or `y-z*b`), where z=y-x.

You can also switch `x` and `y` if you can rewrite `b` to be its negation instead.

Comment: Bonus one: `[-x,~x][b] -> -x-b`

Answer (score 41):

When you have two boolean values, `a` and `b`, if you want to find out if both `a` and `b` are true, use `*` instead of `and`:

```
if a and b: #7 chars
```

vs

```
if a*b: #3 chars
```

if either value is false, it will evaluate as `0` in that statement, and an integer value is only true if it is nonzero.

Comment: Or you could use `&`: `a=b=False`, `a&b`

Comment: use `+` for `or` if you can guarantee `a != -b`

Comment: `|` works in all situations.

Comment: `*` instead of `and`/`&&` saves some bytes in many languages.

Comment: `*` unfortunately only works if what youre comparing are bool variables, otherwise you need parentheses, which cuts out any savings over using `and`, but I have found that `>0<` actually works as an `and`, and at least cuts out a byte or two of whitespace

Comment: Is there a reason to use this over the standard bitwise operators?

Answer (score 39):

Although python doesn't have switch statements, you can emulate them with dictionaries. For example, if you wanted a switch like this:

```python
switch (a):
    case 1:
        runThisCode()
        break
    case 2:
        runThisOtherCode()
        break
    case 3:
        runThisOtherOtherCode()
        break
```

You could use `if` statements, or you could use this:

```python
exec{1:"runThisCode()",2:"runThisOtherCode()",3:"runThisOtherOtherCode()"}[a]
```

or this:

```python
{1:runThisCode,2:runThisOtherCode,3:runThisOtherOtherCode}[a]()
```

which is better if all code paths are functions with the same parameters.

To support a default value do this:

```python
exec{1:"runThisCode()"}.get(a,"defaultCode()")
```

(or this:)

```python
­­{1:runThisCode}.get(a,defaultCode)()
```

One other advantage of this is that if you do have redundancies, you could just add them after the end of the dictionary:

```python
exec{'key1':'code','key2':'code'}[key]+';codeThatWillAlwaysExecute'
```

And if you just wanted to use a switch to return a value:

```python
def getValue(key):
    if key=='blah':return 1
    if key=='foo':return 2
    if key=='bar':return 3
    return 4
```

You could just do this:

```python
getValue=lambda key:{'blah':1,'foo':2,'bar',3}.get(key,4)
```

Comment: This is something i would deeply consider using in the wild. I do so miss my switch statements! +1

Comment: Although instead of using a dictionary with numbered keys in the first example, you should just use a list

Comment: If you have strings as keys, using `dict(s1=v1,s2=v2,...,sn=vn)` instead of `{'s1':v1,'s2':v2,...,'sn':vn}` saves 2*n-4 bytes and is better if n>=3

Comment: Note that the `match` statement was added in 3.10. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/

Answer (score 37):

## PEP448 – [Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

With the release of [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/), manipulation of lists, tuples, sets and dicts just got golfier.

### Turning an iterable into a set/list

Compare the pairs:

```py
set(T)
{*T}

list(T)
[*T]

tuple(T)
(*T,)
```

Much shorter! Note, however, that if you just want to convert something to a list and assign it to a variable, normal [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) is shorter:

```py
L=[*T]
*L,=T
```

A similar syntax works for tuples:

```py
T=*L,
```

which is like extended iterable unpacking, but with the asterisk and comma on the other side.

### Joining lists/tuples

Unpacking is slightly shorter than concatenation if you need to append a list/tuple to both sides:

```py
[1]+T+[2]
[1,*T,2]

(1,)+T+(2,)
(1,*T,2)
```

### Printing the contents of multiple lists

This isn't limited to `print`, but it's definitely where most of the mileage will come from. PEP448 now allows for multiple unpacking, like so:

```py
>>> T = (1, 2, 3)
>>> L = [4, 5, 6]
>>> print(*T,*L)
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

### Updating multiple dictionary items

This probably won't happen very often, but the syntax can be used to save on updating dictionaries if you're updating at least three items:

```py
d[0]=1;d[1]=3;d[2]=5
d={**d,0:1,1:3,2:5}
```

This basically negates any need for `dict.update`.

Comment: This looks worse than Perl, but it works...

Answer (score 36):

loops up to 4 items may be better to supply a tuple instead of using range

```
for x in 0,1,2:
```

vs

```
for x in range(3):
```

Answer (score 36):

#### Use `+=` instead of `append` and `extend`

```python
A.append(B)
```

can be shortened to:

```python
A+=B,
```

`B,` here creates a one-element tuple which can be used to extend `A` just like `[B]` in `A+=[B]`.

---

```python
A.extend(B)
```

can be shortened to:

```python
A+=B
```

Comment: In many (but not all) cases, `return 0` or `return 1` is equivalent to `return False` or `return True`.

Comment: (1) only works if you already know the number is negative, in which case you can save a further 2 characters by simply using a minus sign. `-x` rather than `x*-1`. `--8.32` rather than `-8.32*-1`. Or just `8.32`...

Comment: Quoting the OP: *Please post one tip per answer.*

Comment: Note that in `A+=B` `B` is a `tuple`.

Comment: this can also be used with sets and dicts if you use `|=` in place of `+=`

Answer (score 35):

## Ceil and Floor

If you ever want to get the rounded-up result for a division, much like you'd do with `//` for floor, you could use `math.ceil(3/2)` for 15 or the much shorter `-(-3//2)` for 8 bytes.

```
math.floor(n)   : 13 bytes+12 for import
n//1            : 4  bytes

math.ceil(n)    : 12 bytes+12 for import
-(-n//1)        : 8  bytes
```

Comment: This just saved me close to 20 bytes, thank you!

Comment: sometimes you can get away with `n//1+1` instead of ceil but it does mean ceil(n)=n+1 but it should work for all non integer values

Comment: `round(x)` is `(x+.5)//1`, +1 byte but the latter starts with a `(`, and if `x` is a sum consisting of a constant it can be useful.

Answer (score 32):

Change `import *` to `import*`

---

If you haven't heard, `import*` saves chars!

```
from math import*
```

is only 1 character longer than `import math as m` and you get to remove all instances of `m.`

Even one time use is a saver!

Answer (score 31):

A one line function can be done with lambda:

```
def c(a):
  if a < 3: return a+10
  else: return a-5
```

can be converted to (note missing space `3and` and `10or`)

```
c=lambda a:a<3and a+10or a-5
```

Comment: or `c=lambda a:a+[-5,10][a<3]`. the and/or trick is more useful when you are depending on the shortcircuit behaviour

Comment: In your function, `else: ` can be dropped as `return` stops the execution of the function, so everything that follows is only executed if the `if` condition failed, aka if the  `else` condition is true. Thus `else` can safely be ommited. (Explained in details for the neophytes out there)

Comment: c(-10) returns -15 while it should return 0

Comment: or `c=lambda a:a-5+15*(a<3)`

Answer (score 30):

### Exploit Python 2 string representations

Python 2 lets you convert an object `x` to its string representation `` `x` `` at a cost of only 2 chars. Use this for tasks that are easier done on the object's string than the object itself.

**Join characters**

Given a list of characters `l=['a','b','c']`, one can produce `''.join(l)` as `` `l`[2::5] ``, which saves a byte.

The reason is that `` `l` `` is  `"['a', 'b', 'c']"` (with spaces), so one can extract the letters with a list slice, starting that the second zero-indexed character `a`, and taking every fifth character from there. This doesn't work to join multi-character strings or escape characters represented like `'\n'`.

**Concatenate digits**

Similarly, given a non-empty list of digits like `l=[0,3,5]`, one can concatenate them into a string `'035'` as `` `l`[1::3] ``.

This saves doing something like `map(str,l)`. Note that they must be single digits, and can't have floats like `1.0` mixed in. Also, this fails on the empty list, producing `]`.

**Check for negatives**

Now, for a non-string task. Suppose you have a list `l` of real numbers and want to test if it contains any negative numbers, producing a Boolean.

You can do

```python
'-'in`l`
```

which checks for a negative sign in the string rep. This shorter than either of

```python
any(x<0for x in l)
min(l+[0])<0
```

For the second, `min(l)<0` would fail on the empty list, so you have to hedge.

Comment: Concatenating single digits string slicing is also effective in Python 3, albeit less so: `str(l)[2::5]` is 12 bytes, versus 19 for `''.join(map(str,l))`. An actual situation where this came up (where `l` was a generator statement, not a list) saved me just one byte... which is still worth it!

Answer (score 30):

### Length tradeoff reference

I've think it would be useful to have a reference for the character count differences for some common alternative ways of doing things, so that I can know when to use which. I'll use `_` to indicate an expression or piece of code.

**Assign to a variable: +4**

```python
x=_;x
_
```

So, this breaks even if you

- Use `_` a second time: `_` has length 5
- Use `_` a third time: `_` has length 3

**Assign variables separately: 0**

```python
x,y=a,b
x=a;y=b
```

- -2 when `a` equals `b` for `x=y=a`

**Expand `lambda` to function `def`: +7**

```python
lambda x:_
def f(x):return _
```

- -2 for named functions
- -1 if `_` can touch on the left
- -1 in Python 2 if can `print` rather than return
- +1 for starred input `*x`

Generically, if you're `def` to save an expression to a variable used twice, this breaks even when the expression is length 12.

```python
lambda x:g(123456789012,123456789012)
def f(x):s=123456789012;return g(s,s)
```

**STDIN rather than function: +1**

```python
def f(x):_;print s
x=input();_;print s
```

- -1 for line of code needed in `_` if not single-line
- +4 if `raw_input` needed in Python 2
- -4 if input variable used only once
- +1 if function must `return` rather than `print` in Python 2

**Use `exec` rather than looping over `range(n)`: +0**

```python
for i in range(n):_
i=0;exec"_;i+=1;"*n
```

- +2 for Python 3 `exec()`
- -4 if shifted range `range(c,c+n)` for single-char `c`
- -5 when going backwards from `n` to `1` via `range(n,0,-1)`
- -9 if index variable never used

**Apply `map` manually in a loop: +0**

```python
for x in l:y=f(x);_
for y in map(f,l):_
```

**Apply `map` manually in a list comprehension: +8**

```python
map(f,l)
[f(x)for x in l]
```

- -12 when `f` must be written in the `map` as the `lambda` expression `lambda x:f(x)`, causing overall 4 char loss.

**Apply `filter` manually in a list comprehension: +11**

```python
filter(f,l)
[x for x in l if f(x)]
```

- -1 if `f(x)` expression can touch on the left
- -12 when `f` must be written in the `filter` as the `lambda` expression `lambda x:f(x)`, causing overall 1 char loss.

**Import* versus import single-use: +4**

```python
import _;_.f
from _ import*;f
```

- Breaks even when `_` has length 5
- `import _ as x;x.f` is always worse except for multiple imports
- `__import__('_').f` is also worse

Thanks to @Sp3000 for lots of suggestions and fixes.

Comment: The "exec" bit goes -9 if you don't need the index.

Answer (score 28):

## Assignment expressions

[Assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) are a powerful language feature introduced in [Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380a1/) ([TIO](https://tio.run/#python38pr)). Use the "walrus operator" `:=` to assign a variable inline as part of expression.

```python
>>> (n:=2, n+1)
(2, 3)
```

You can save an expression to a variable inside a `lambda`, where assignments are not ordinarily allowed. Compare:

```python
def f(s):t=s.strip();return t+t[::-1]
lambda s:s.strip()+s.strip()[::-1]
lambda s:(t:=s.strip())+t[::-1]
```

An assignment expression can be used in a comprehension to iteratively update a value, storing the result after each step in a list or other collection. This example computes a running sum by updating the running total `t`.

```python
>>> t=0
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> print([t:=t+x for x in l])
[1, 3, 6]
>>> t
6
```

This can be done in a `lambda` with the initial value as an optional argument:

```python
>>> f=lambda l,t=0:[t:=t+x for x in l]
>>> f([1,2,3])
[1, 3, 6]
```

This function is reusable: each call with start `t` back at 0.

Comment: This changes everything!

Comment: What is Python infamous for? Oh... nevermind.

Answer (score 27):

## Common helper functions

These are some golfed implementations of number theoretic functions that come up in challenges a lot. Many of these are due to xnor, especially the “Wilson’s theorem prime machines” of the form `lambda n,i=1,p=1`. The coprime/totient functions are Dennis’s [(explanation here)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104681/3852).

It is instructive to study what exactly these are doing, so that you can adapt them to your needs or roll them into another recursive function. That often ends up being shorter than pasting these directly into your solution as-is!

All of these assume `n` is a positive integer. The ones marked with an asterisk produce the wrong result if `n = 1`. Furthermore, these snippets assume Python 2. For Python 3, you might need to replace `/` by `//` here and there.

```python
# Function                                                   Output of f(360)
#========================================================================================
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i*[0]and[f(n,i+1),[i]+f(n/i)][n%i<1]      # [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5] (slow!)
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i*[0]and f(n,i+1)if n%i else[i]+f(n/i)    # [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i*[0]and(n%i and f(n,i+1)or[i]+f(n/i))    # [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
f=lambda n,i=2:n<2and{1}or n%i and f(n,i+1)or{i}|f(n/i)    # {1, 2, 3, 5}
f=lambda n,i=2:n<2and{i}or n%i and f(n,i+1)or{i}|f(n/i,i)  #*{2, 3, 5}
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i and[f(n,i+1),i+f(n/i)][n%i<1]           # 2+2+2+3+3+5 (slow!)
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i and f(n,i+1)if n%i else i+f(n/i)        # 2+2+2+3+3+5
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i and(n%i and f(n,i+1)or i+f(n/i))        # 2+2+2+3+3+5
f=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n*[0]and p%i*[i]+f(n-p%i,i+1,p*i*i)     # first n primes
f=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n*[0]and p%i*[i]+f(n-1,i+1,p*i*i)       # primes <= n
f=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n/i and p%i*i+f(n,i+1,p*i*i)            # sum of primes <= n
f=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n/i and p%i+f(n,i+1,p*i*i)              # count primes <= n
f=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n and-~f(n-p%i,i+1,p*i*i)               # nth prime
f=lambda n:all(n%m for m in range(2,n))                    #*is n prime? (not recursive)
f=lambda n:1>>n or n*f(n-1)                                # factorial
f=lambda n:sum(k/n*k%n>n-2for k in range(n*n))             # totient phi(n) (not recursive)
f=lambda n:[k/n for k in range(n*n)if k/n*k%n==1]          # coprimes up to n (not recursive)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tdXBkppAEAbgu0/RkbJ2BnEVLHMgYm655gFYDsSF2CU0FDMk2TLm1U2P4kqpqDkEsEos/ab9e2Yo3/SqIG@HeVlUGtSb6vHrWSW6SpZ1pbCgDHPUYjrhQ/bSmpYKAuj3@y87C77wrebvwL8fX2td1hqKFFIx/ci0Ffyno5cGWZx/e42BHAw8n8Zoh5MoptcwFfzR0JVOiNGQb8Yoo5AGOHejQ5UWhJ4Dh2u6v2YRCJUVPz/IbheOLqbAGiSZSk4jdLndnjBI2y2qE/e4N/fY2LjbooJLcIPb3@36Nu4Rm207JLwjOcay7E0nM97/9NQFvNqDphHe0JxTPmc3OgAd8QO20r8AO6Arub87j0CuUwauT8dZUQ64oYe@jfi9EZ3SRrspyoIUK6WBoKwwT9TDlnsuGetgwDwAugo1URln/5cujQZSdW5W6ePeDc14y6ImfZcz2OhPR1JtjvTqgLUYP84y7l0OKTcsBySoYvqeCM8hKa9tRpaN6pj7ZxBUaGj2vx9Je5b57mJBYGa9vQ9e3tvluKfxUhcVxlmb4UzFekz2ekALGnmmzPWpTLLPy7RAFxoTk9sKBclbJYYMwxWRF0MzZBC0l5bpSNONuuRxOIczfce7fc@ImRH3j4BnnqgVlkI@qzLjx8PTCz3J0PMjH5JfyRKyTyZMrjcV3kTu/gI)

Additions and byte saves are very welcome!

Comment: #7 has a redundant space after `)`. (Also it has a variant similar to #2.)

Comment: Um ... can `f=lambda n:1>>n or n*f(n-1)` be `lambda n:n<2or n*f(n-1)`, or am I going crazy?

Comment: That looks like an acceptable alternative whenever it's acceptable that `f(0) == f(1) == True` rather than `1`.

Comment: Oh, totally forgot about that >_<.

Comment: In Python 3.8, `from math import perm as f` is shorter than `factorial` definition. and that gives a shorter way to check primality using Wilson's theorem if `math` is already imported  (first used in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218738/69850, ls mentioned in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194319/69850)

Comment: "is n non-prime": `0in{n%m for m in range(2,n)}`

Answer (score 25):

## Arithmetic tricks

Here are some arithmetic tricks which are either shorter or are more useful due to precedence rules.

```
Assumptions                  Version 1        Version 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
n >= 0 float                 n==0             0**n
n >= 0 integer               n==0             1>>n
n >  0 integer               n!=1             1%n
n >  0 integer, Python 2     n==1             1/n
n, m float                   n!=m             n-m
```

Comment: `1//n` could still be useful in Python 3 for `n==1` since they have different precedence.

Answer (score 25):

## Printing a string without a trailing newline in Python 3

Suppose you have a string `s`, and need to print it without a trailing newline. The canonical way of doing this would be

```py
print(s,end='')
```

However, if we look at the [documentation for `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), we can see that `print` takes in a variable number of objects as its first parameter, with "variable number" including zero. This means that we can do

```py
print(end=s)
```

instead, for a saving of 3 bytes.

Note that this only works when `s` is a string, since otherwise the conversion to string would be too expensive:

```py
print(1,end='')
print(end=str(1))
```

Thanks to [@Reticality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49950/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-of-input/49998#comment118031_49998) for this tip.

Comment: Note for `\`\`` commenters: `\`\`` does not work in Python 3 (This is a spam prevention comment)

Answer (score 25):

## The shortest infinite for comprehension

You may know the trick to easily create an infinite generator using the two-argument form of `iter`:

```
(... for _ in iter(lambda:0,1))
```

where `0` and `1` can be any two non-equal values.

As [@ovs once pointed out to me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236762/write-an-infinitely-nested-generator-comprehension/236763#comment537666_236763), you can replace `lambda:0` with `int`, because `int` returns 0 when called with no arguments.

```
(... for _ in iter(int,1))
```

However, we can do one byte better!:

```
(... for()in iter(set,1))
```

This uses the fact that `()` is a valid L-value (assignment target) in Python as long as the RHS is an empty sequence, and `set` returns an empty set when called with no arguments.

You can also use `str` instead of `set` for the same byte count.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237487/107561) numpy trick

Answer (score 24):

```
>>> for i in range(x):s+=input()
```

if value of **i** is useless:

```
>>> for i in[0]*x:s+=input()
```

or

```
>>> exec's+=input();'*x
```

Comment: You can make the second example into `for i in[0]*x:s+=input()` to save another space. Also, you can remove the space between the exec and the first quotation mark to get `exec's+=input();'*x`

Comment: shouldn't the second line be: `for i in[0]*x:s+=input()`

Comment: [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/5047#5047) (newer but more upvotes)

Answer (score 23):

Multiple statements can be put on one line separated by `;`. This can save a lot of whitespace from indentation.

```
while foo(a):
 print a;a*=2
```

Or even better:

```
while foo(a):print a;a*=2
```

Comment: you can save one more by putting this one all on one line

Comment: Not always possible if you have other compound statements like `if`s and `while`s inside the `while`.

Answer (score 22):

### Binomial coefficient

The binomial coefficient \$\binom{n}{k} \ = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\$ can be expressed arithmetically as

```
((2**n+1)**n>>n*k)%2**n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n20pDw0hLK0/bUBNI2tnlaWVrqoIE/qflFynkKWTmKRQl5qWnahgaaFpxKYAEsxGCIG1WBUWZeSUKaRpAwzR1uBTA3P8A)

This works for \$n,k \geq 0\$, except for \$n=k=0\$ it gives \$0\$ rather than \$1\$. More generally, it works to use

```
(b+1)**n/b**k%b
```

[(TIO)](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoAgEADvvmIvgZpQdlPoMS5libWKdOn1Zl06zsBMvq890VQrzsYY5ufDnbg4IBUtx14LKWlAKWOH1acCBIGgONpWrkdhGbwy/pJaYnMJdIHnbSIUgw/rAw), where \$b\$ is any value strictly greater than the result. The first expression uses \$b=2^n\$, which exceeds \$\binom{n}{k}\$ except for \$n=k=0\$.

---

Why does this work? Let's look at an example with `b=1000`. Then, for `n=6`, we have

```
(b+1)**n = 1001 ** 6 = 1006015020015006001
```

Note how triples of digits encode the binomial coefficients in the `n=6` row of Pascal's triangle:

```
1   6  15  20  15   6   1
1 006 015 020 015 006 001
```

This works because the binomial coefficients are the coefficients of the polynomial

$$ (b+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b^k$$

and so can be read off as digits in base `b`, as long no binomial coefficient exceeds `b` which would cause regrouping.

We can extract a given triple of digits, say for \$\binom{6}{2}=15\$, by floor-dividing by `1000000` to delete the last 6 digits leaving `1006015020015`, then take `%1000` to extract the last triplet `015`. More generally, doing `/b**k%b` extracts the `k`-th digit from the end zero-indexed in base `b`, that is the digit with multiplier `b**k`.

Comment: Why is this a tip for golfing in Python? Many languages have built-ins for exponentiation.

Comment: Some challenges don't allow you to use imports

Comment: Even when imports are allowed it can save some bytes because the `import math` followed by `math.comb(n,k)` is longer.

Answer (score 19):

## Translating chars in a string

I've seen this situation pop up a few times, so I thought a tip would be good.

Suppose you have a string `s` and you want to translate some chars of `s` to other chars (think ROT-13 like ciphers). For a more concrete example, suppose we want to swap just the `a`s and `b`s in a string, e.g.

```py
"abacus" -> "babcus"
```

The naïve way to do this would be:

```py
lambda s:s.replace('a','T').replace('b','a').replace('T','b')
```

Note how we need to introduce a temporary `'T'` to get the swapping right.

With `eval`, we can shorten this a bit:

```py
lambda s:eval("s"+".replace('%s','%s')"*3%tuple("aTbaTb"))
```

For this particular example, iterating char-by-char gives a slightly better solution (feel free to try it!). But even so, the winner is **`str.translate`**, which takes a dictionary of `from: to` code points:

```py
# Note: 97 is 'a' and 98 is 'b'
lambda s:s.translate({97:98,98:97})
```

In Python 2 this only works for Unicode strings, so unfortunately the code here is slightly longer:

```py
lambda s:(u''+s).translate({97:98,98:97})
```

Some important points which make `str.translate` so useful are:

- It's easily extendable.
- Any char not specified is untouched by default, e.g. the `"cus"` in `"abacus"` above.
- The `to` part of the dictionary can actually be a (Unicode) string as well, e.g. `{97:"XYZ"}` (`u"XYZ"` in Python 2) would turn `abacus -> XYZbXYZcus`. It can also be `None`, but that doesn't save any bytes compared to `""` or `u""`.

Comment: `"ab".translate({97:None})` is longer than `"ab".translate({97:""})`.

Comment: @T.Verron Thanks for pointing that out - I'm not sure why I added that there tbh...

Comment: The second example you gave can be shortened: replace "aTbaTb" with "aTb"*2. Also, you neglected to mention maketrans here, which could significantly shorten translations involving many characters, e.g.: `from string import*;t="abcdefghijklmABCDEFGHIJKLMZYXWVUTSRQPONzyxwvutsrqpon";lambda s:s.translate(maketrans(t,t[::-1]))`

Comment: `tuple("aTbaTb")` -> `(*"aTb"*2,)`

Comment: Worth noting is that, while .translate accepts a mapping of unicode values to replacement characters or values, a string can be indexed the same as a dict with integer keys. Thus, {97:98,98:97} may be replaced with 'ab'*99 in the call to .translate, as b and a will be at each others' indices in the resulting string.

Answer (score 18):

### Safely get the first element

You can check if a possibly-empty list `l` starts with a value `x` by doing

```python
l[:1]==[x]
```

This gives `False` on an empty list, while `l[0]==x` gives an out-of-bounds error. Strings works similarly

```python
s[:1]=='a'
```

In general, you can safely check the `n`'th element as

```python
l[n:n+1]==[a]
```

or as `l[n:][:1]==[a]` when `n` is a long expression.

Answer (score 17):

## Reading multi-line input

In Python 3, the built-in function `open` underwent some changes. In particular, its first argument

> *file* is either a string or bytes object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped.

([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open))

That means

```
open(0).read()
```

suffices to read all input from STDIN.

Try it online on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/duzBEE).

Comment: ... except on Windows :/ (`OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid`)

Answer (score 16):

If you're doing somewhat more complex golfing that require something from the standard library to be used a lot, `import x as y` can save some space:

```
import itertools as i
i.groupby(...) # same as itertools.groupby
```

Comment: You can also do from itertools import *. This uses up 2 more characters, but you hit equal immediately by typing groupby instead of i.groupby. If you use groupby twice, you just saved 2 characters!

Comment: from blah import* (without the last whitespace) is even shorter.

Comment: import* also gets you all the rest of the itertools. I wish it were shorter to use product/combinations/permutations though

Comment: Yeah, the names in `itertools` are just *way* too descriptive, makes me sad.

Answer (score 16):

### Replace a value in a list

To replace every entry of value `a` with `b` in a list `L`, use:

`map({a:b}.get,L,L)`

For example,

```python
L=[1,2,3,1,2,3]
a=2
b=3
print map({a:b}.get,L,L)

[1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3]  #Output
```

In Python 3, this returns a `map` object rather than a list. The list entries can be any hashable values (ints, floats, strings, tuples, etc).

Here's how this works. A dictionary's `get` method takes a key and default value, and returns the dictionary's entry for that key, using the default value is the key is not present. This method is mapped method over each entry in `L` both as the key and the default value, which results in

```python
[{a:b}.get(x,x) for x in L]
```

If `x` is `a`, then the dictionary transforms it to `b`, and otherwise, it defaults to itself. You can perform multiple replacements at the same time using a larger dictionary.

Credit to [twobit on Anarchy Golf](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Swap%20The%20Characters/twobit_1413325607&py) for exposing me to this trick.

Answer (score 16):

## Negating Booleans

So you have a Boolean... a real Boolean, not one [represented as an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18983/13959). You have a condition where it needs to be negated, and you can't just go back and negate it where you got it (e.g. `!=` instead of `==`), maybe because you use it once straight and once negated.

Well, who says your Booleans aren't longing to be integers deep in their little hearts?

```py
>>> False < 1
True
>>> True < 1
False
```

8 bytes, not counting the colon:

```py
if not C:
```

6 bytes:

```py
if C<1:
```

**EDIT:** 5 bytes, thanks to user202729 in the comments:

```py
if~-C:
```

This works because:

```py
>>> -False
0
>>> -True
-1
>>> ~-False
-1
>>> ~-True
0
```

Answer (score 16):

### Split into chunks

You can split a list into chunks of a given size using `zip` and `iter`, as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2233204).

```python
>>> l=range(12)
>>> zip(*[iter(l)]*4)
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11)]
```

Of course, substituting in `l` as `zip(*[iter(range(12))]*4)` gives the same result.

The `4` is the number of elements per chunk. If the length isn't a multiple of this, any elements in the remainder are not included. For example, `l=range(13)` would give the same result.

The result is a list of tuples. If your input is a string and you want to produce a list of strings, you can do

```python
>>> l="Code_golf"
>>> map(''.join,zip(*[iter(l)]*3)) 
['Cod', 'e_g', 'olf'] # Python 3 would give a map object
```

When the list `l` is defined by a list comprehension, instead of converting to an iterable as `iter(l)`, you can instead write it as a generator comprehension with `(...)` instead of `[...]`.

```python
>>> l=(n for n in range(18)if n%3!=1)
>>> zip(*[l]*4)
[(0, 2, 3, 5), (6, 8, 9, 11), (12, 14, 15, 17)]
```

This consumes the generator, so `l` will appear empty afterwards. Note as before that we can inline `l` as `zip(*[(n for n in range(18)if n%3!=1)]*4)`.

Answer (score 15):

`map` can take multiple iterable arguments and apply the function in parallel.

Instead of

```
a=[1,4,2,6,4]
b=[2,3,1,8,2]
map(lambda x,y:...,zip(a,b))
```

you can write

```
map(lambda x,y:...,a,b)
```

Comment: I didn't know this and it's super useful!

Answer (score 14):

You only need to indent nested control structures:

```
def baz(i):
 if i==0:i=1;print i;bar()
 while i:i+=foo(i-1)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use default arguments of a function to save some indentation, since

```python
def f(a,l=[1,2,3]):
 return sum(a==i for i in l)
```

is one byte shorter than

```python
def f(a):
 l=[1,2,3]
 return sum(a==i for i in l)
```

Comment: A small caution: if a list that is passed in as an optional argument is modified in the function (like with `pop` or `l[0] =1`), that list will be changed in the outer scope too.

Comment: Also, this is only needed if the function body contains nested block statements; otherwise, you can just put everything on one line to avoid indentation.

Answer (score 14):

## `None` arguments in Python builtins

### map (Python 2 only)

Mapping with `None` in place of a function assumes the identity function instead. This allows it to be used as an alternative to `itertools.izip_longest` for zipping lists to the length of the longest list:

```py
>>> L = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7]]
>>> map(None,*L)
[(1, 3, 7), (2, 4, None), (None, 5, None), (None, 6, None)]
```

For visualisation (with `.` representing `None`):

```py
1 2                1 3 7
3 4 5 6      ->    2 4 .
7                  . 5 .
                   . 6 .
```

### filter

`filter` with `None` also assumes the identity function, thus removing falsy elements.

```py
>>> L = ["", 1, 0, [5], [], None, (), (4, 2)]
>>> filter(None, L)
[1, [5], (4, 2)]
```

This is a bit better than a list comprehension:

```py
filter(None,L)
[x for x in L if x]
```

However, as @KSab notes, if all elements are of the same type then there may be shorter alternatives, e.g. `filter(str,L)` if all elements are strings.

Comment: I had no idea you could do this! In the case of the filter, something similar I have done in the past is `filter(str,L)` if L is all strings or `filter(int,L)` if all ints which in some cases could be shorter.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to know the type of a variable x:

```
x*0is 0  # -> integer
x*0==0   # -> float (if the previous check fails)
x*0==""  # -> string
x*0==[]  # -> array
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `os.read` to read all input:

```
import os
s=os.read(0,1e9)
```

Which is shorter than

```
import sys
s=sys.stdin.read()
```

Note that this has a limitation on input length, but it's so ridiculously large I'd say we're safe from the angry mob.

Comment: `raw_input()` is shorter. If you need to read once, just spelling it out is shorter than the import + os.read; if more than once, assign it to a single-character value.

Comment: @Wooble: why use raw_input for golfing? just use input.

Comment: @Lie: good point; although it depends on the problem specification whether having input evaluated would work, you can just stipulate that you're using python 3 (although then your print functions require a bit more space...)

Comment: This doesn't work in python2.7/3. The number of bytes to read must be an integer.

Comment: raw_input isn't available in Python 3 - use int(input()) instead.

Comment: @hosch250: I use `raw_input` with Python3.

Comment: @MathieuRodic I tried to use `raw_input` with my installation, but the program wouldn't compile.  It said it wasn't available.  Are you sure you aren't using Python 2, or maybe a dual installation?

Comment: Maybe it is due to the dual installation indeed...

Comment: `1e9` -> `9e9`.

Answer (score 13):

Use extended slicing to select one of two strings

```
>>> for x in-2,2:print"WoolrlledH"[::x]
... 
Hello
World
```

vs

```
>>> for x in 0,1:print["Hello","World"][x]
... 
Hello
World
```

Comment: Made redundant by http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/407/4999

Answer (score 13):

Just found out two new things. First, `input()` can parse tuples, like `1, 2, 3` is equivalent to the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`.

And if you need to convert a value to float, just multiply by `1.`. Yes, `1.` is valid syntax (At least in 2.6).

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in Python 2, `input(x)` is basically the same thing as `eval(raw_input(x))`. Unsafe to use in practice, but good for code golfing.

Comment: Quoting the OP: *Please post one tip per answer.*

Comment: To further explicate the point of this answer: in a challenge where input format is flexible, for instance if reading in a bunch of numerical arguments, you can write `input()` only once. E.g. `a,b,c=input()` will read in three comma-separated arguments and assign them to a, b, and c

Comment: Can't you also just divide by `1` to save 1 byte?, because division always gives a float

Answer (score 13):

If you represent boolean values as numbers you can save characters. This is especially true for using `-1` as `True`.

Bitty conditionals work (Truth table):

```
a  b   &  |  ^ 
0  0   0  0  0
0  -1  0 -1 -1
-1 0   0 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1  0
```

And `~` works as not:

```
 a ~a
 0 -1
-1  0
```

Even though the `-` for initializing `-1` costs one character, this can easily save characters overall.

Compare:

```
while~a:
```

to:

```
while not a:
```

Answer (score 13):

**Adding vectors**

Python doesn't have a built-in way to do vector (component-wise) addition except with libraries. Say `a` and `b` are two equal-length lists of numbers you want to add. Instead of the list comprehension

```python
c=[a[i]+b[i]for i in range(len(a))]
```

you can use

```python
c=map(sum,zip(a,b))
```

This produces an annoying `map` object in Python 3, but it's shorter even if you have to convert to a list.

Comment: `map(int.__add__,a,b)` is more readable with 1 char longer.

Comment: @est But this is code golf...

Comment: If you end up needing other stuff from the `operator` module anyway, `from operator import*` will allow `map(int.__add__,a,b)` to shorten 8 characters to `map(add,a,b)`.

Comment: Also, the conversion to `list` can be pretty cheap, character-wise, either `*c,=map(sum,zip(a,b))` (when you're assigning to a name as a statement, adds two characters over Py2 version) or `[*map(sum,zip(a,b))]` (for use as an expression, adds three characters over Py2's `map`).

Answer (score 13):

### Object method as answer

Your submission can be a method of an object

```python
range(123,790,111).count
```

This defines an anonymous function much shorter than

```python
lambda n:range(123,790,111).count(n)
```

The object method is a valid function that meets our definition. For example, it could be bound and called

```python
f=range(123,790,111).count
print f(99)
```

Because it avoids a costly `lambda`, this saves characters even rewriting from

```python
lambda n:n in range(123,790,111)
```

Consider using an object method when your solution is a simple two-input function of your input and some concrete object. You can use `dir()` to get a list of methods of an object. Note in particular methods like `.__add__` that are called for an operator like `+`. Most infix operators correspond to a method.

Other examples:

```python
"prefix{}suffix".format
lambda s:"prefix"+s+"suffix"

2 .__rpow__    #Space for lexer
lambda n:n*n

[0,0].__le__
lambda l:[0,0]<=l
```

You can even sometimes save bytes with two input [by currying](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8427/20260). For example, compare

```python
lambda l:expression_in_l.count
lambda n,l:n in expression_in_l
```

where `expression_in_l` produces a list with no duplicates and has favorable spacing and precedence.

Comment: `["North","East","South","West"].pop` a function submission must work multiple times, no? using `.__getitem__` would do the trick, but the length would be the same

Answer (score 13):

### Use `.center` in ASCII art

In drawing a symmetrical ASCII art, you can center-justify each line in a fixed width of spaces. For example, `"<|>".center(7)` gives `'  <|>  '`. This can be shorter than computing how many spaces are needed to center it.

You can also pad with a different character by doing `"<|>".center(7,'_')`

Comment: This is actually really cool!

Comment: I wish JS had this function...

Comment: Would `f"{'<|>':^7}"` not be shorter in python3.6+ for non-variable widths? Even more so when providing the character to center by, `f"{'<|>':-^7}"` vs `"<|>".center(7,"-")`

Answer (score 12):

### Make a mutable matrix

If you want to make a 3*4 grid of zeroes, the natural expression `M=[[0]*4]*3` gives an unpleasant surprise if you modify an entry:

```python
>>> M=[[0]*4]*3
>>> M
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> M[0][0]=1
>>> M
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Since each row is a copy of the same list by reference, modifying one row modifies all of them, which is usually not the behavior you want.

In Python 2, avoid this with the hack (19 chars):

```python
M=eval(`[[0]*4]*3`)
```

Doing `` eval(`_`) `` converts to the string representation, then re-evaluates it, converting the object to the code of how it's displayed. In effect, it's doing `copy.deepcopy`.

If you're OK getting a tuple of lists, you can do (18 chars):

```python
M=eval('[0]*4,'*3)
```

to get `([0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0])`. This lets you do `M[0][0]=1` but not `M[0]=[1,2,3,4]`. It also works in Python 3.

Comment: what about python3?

Comment: @micsthepick Good question. You can use `str` for backticks as `M=eval(str([[0]*3]*4))`. Or, `M=[3*[0]for _ in[0]*4]` which is the same length. Maybe there's better.

Answer (score 12):

### Avoid `startswith`

The string method `startswith` is too long. There are shorter ways to check if a string `s` starts with a prefix `t` of unknown length.

```python
t<=s<t+'~'     #Requires a char bigger than any in s,t
s.find(t)==0
s[:len(t)]==t    
s.startswith(t)
```

The second one is well-suited for the truth/falsity of the negation.

```python
if s.find(t):
```

Comment: `s[:len(t)]==t` is shorter if `t` has a constant length less than 100000.

Answer (score 12):

## The best way to check whether is a number even or not

Usually you do it this way (6 bytes):

```python
n%2==0
```

But you can reduce it to 5 bytes:

```python
n%2<1
```

And even 4 bytes:

```python
~n&1
```

Bonus tip: when you use `if` you can ignore spacebetween `if` and `~n&1` this way:

```python
if~n&1:
```

Answer (score 11):

use `os.urandom()` as a random source instead of `random.randint()`

Comment: Doesn't this require use of `ord()` to get a number instead of character? `len("ord(os.urandom(1))")` -> `18` and `len("random.randint()")` -> `16`

Comment: @Josh, don't forget you need to `import random` vs `import os`. randint() needs 3 parameters anyway. If you need a list of random numbers, you can use `map(ord,os.urandom(N))` Also, sometimes, you actually need a random char instead of a number

Comment: Late to the party, but if you only need a few random numbers, try using `id(id)`, substituting the inner `id` with any 3-letter builtin if you need more than one. `'abc'[id(id)%3]` is 11 characters shorter than `'abc'[random.randrange(3)]`, not even counting the import statement.

Comment: @Fraxtil `id` can be applied on mostly everything, such as `1` or `[]`.

Comment: If you want to generate random bytes, of course.

Answer (score 11):

**Iterating over indices in a list**

Sometimes, you need to iterate over the indices of a list `l` in order to do something for each element that depends on its index. The obvious way is a clunky expression:

```python
# 38 chars
for i in range(len(l)):DoStuff(i,l[i])
```

The Pythonic solution is to use `enumerate`:

```python
# 36 chars
for i,x in enumerate(l):DoStuff(i,x)
```

But that nine-letter method is just too long for golfing.

Instead, just manually track the index yourself while iterating over the list.

```python
# 32 chars
i=0
for x in l:DoStuff(i,x);i+=1
```

Here's some alternatives that are longer but might be situationally better

```python
# 36 chars
# Consumes list
i=0
while l:DoStuff(i,l.pop(0));i+=1

# 36 chars
i=0
while l[i:]:DoStuff(i,l[i]);i+=1
```

Answer (score 11):

## Use complex numbers to find the distance between two points

Say you have two 2-element tuples which represent points in the Euclidean plane, e.g. `x=(0, 0)` and `y=(3, 4)`, and you want to find the distance between them. The naïve way to do this is

```
d=((x[0]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-y[1])**2)**.5
```

Using complex numbers, this becomes:

```
c=complex;d=abs(c(*x)-c(*y))
```

If you have access to each coordinate individually, say `a=0, b=0, c=3, d=4`, then

```
abs(a-c+(b-d)*1j)
```

can be used instead.

Comment: Only 3 chars longer is `d=abs(x[0]-y[0]+(x[1]-y[1])*1j)`. Can this be made shorter than what you have? I'm just wondering if `1j` could be useful in converting a tuple to a complex number.

Comment: @mbomb007 It depends on what you have I guess. If you need to process the individual numbers in the two tuples anyway, then `*1j` is usually shorter.

Comment: In this case, it's the list subscription that's expensive. Consider, instead of `x=(0,0);y=(3,4);c=complex;d=abs(c(*x)-c(*y))`, different assignments: `a,b=0,0;c,d=3,4;d=((a-c)**2+(b-d)**2)**.5`. Yes, writing `x=0,0;y=3,4` does indeed make the complex option shorter, but using different assignments makes it even shorter: `x=0,0;y=3,4;c=complex;d=abs(c(*x)-c(*y)`. Finally, consider @mbomb007's approach with different assignments: `a,b=0,0;x,y=3,4;d=abs(a-x+(b-y)*1j)`: with or without the assignment, it's shorter than all of the alternatives I've found.

Comment: @Ogaday This tip's been long overdue for the `1j` part, so I've added that in. The general point was basically that `((a-b)**2+(c-d)**2)**.5` is rarely ever needed.

Answer (score 11):

## Leak variables to save on assignment

Combining with [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1020/21487), suppose you have a situation like

```py
for _ in[0]*x:doSomething()
a="blah"
```

You can instead do:

```py
for a in["blah"]*x:doSomething()
```

to skip out on a variable assignment. However, be aware that

```py
exec"doSomething();"*x;a="blah"
```

in Python 2 is *just* shorter, so this only really saves in cases like assigning a char (via `"c"*x`) or in Python 3.

However, where things get fun is with Python 2 list comprehensions, where this idea still works due to a [quirk with list comprehension scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-thi):

```py
[doSomething()for a in["blah"]*x]
```

*(Credits to @xnor for expanding the former, and @Lembik for teaching me about the latter)*

Comment: Does the last one not work in Python 3?

Comment: @xnor in Python 3 exec requires parentheses, so it would be one character longer than the for... format.

Answer (score 11):

## Use *f-strings*

Python 3.6 [introduces a new string literal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) that is vastly more byte-efficient at variable interpolation than using `%` or `.format()` in non-trivial cases. For example, you can write:

```
l='Python';b=40;print(f'{l}, {b} bytes')
```

instead of

```
l='Python';b=43;print('%s, %d bytes'%(l,b))
```

Comment: At the time of writing, getting a Python 3.6 pre-release to run on Windows is a more difficult matter... ^^;

Comment: *cough* ...linux ftw... *cough*

Comment: If you get MinGW, you could just build from source

Comment: It's shorter in trivial cases, too. Compare `' '+str(n)` (10 bytes) and `f' {n}'` (7 bytes).

Comment: The better comparison would be with `' %d'%n` I think, where this example doesn't save any bytes. You do need more args for this to help

Comment: Also to note, this does _not_ trip up `if'foo'==bar:` or `foo if'bar'else 6` as the `if` is lex-ed (?) before `f''`. Also, this helps where `%` may have lower precedence than other operators, removing the need for brackets.

Answer (score 11):

### Abuse `==` short circuiting

If you have:

- A function with a side effect (such as `print`);
- That you only want to run if some condition is (or is not) met.

Then you might be able to use `==` over `or`  to save a byte.

Here's printing all numbers `n` under 100 that have `f(n)` less than 2:

```python
# Naive
for n in range(100):f(n)<2and print(n)
# Invert condition
for n in range(100):f(n)>1or print(n)
# Use ==
for n in range(100):f(n)<2==print(n)
```

Answer (score 10):

### Store 8-bit numbers compactly as a bytes object  in Python 3

In Python 3, a *bytes object* is written as a string literal preceded by a `b`, like `b"golf"`. It acts much like a tuple of the `ord` values of its characters.

```python
>>> l=b"golf"
>>> list(l)
[103, 111, 108, 102]
>>> l[2]
108
>>> 108 in l
True
>>> max(l)
111
>>> for x in l:print(x)
103
111
108
102
```

Python 2 also has bytes objects but they act as strings, so this only works in Python 3.

This gives a shorter way to express an explicit list of numbers between 0 to 255. Use this to hardcode data. It uses one byte per number, plus three bytes overhead for `b""`.  For example, the list of the first 9 primes `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23]` compresses to 14 bytes rather than 24. (An extra byte is used for a workaround explained below for character 13.)

In many cases, your bytes object will contain non-printable characters such as `b"\x01x02\x03"` for `[1, 2, 3]`. These are written with hex escape characters, but [you may use them a single characters in your code](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4922/20260) (unless the challenge says otherwise) even though SE will not display them. But, characters like the carriage return `b"\x0D"` will break your code, so you need to use the two-char escape sequence `"\r"`.

Answer (score 10):

## Avoid `list.insert`

Instead of `list.insert`, appending to a slice is shorter:

```py
L.insert(i,x)
L[:i]+=x,
```

For example:

```py
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L[:-2]+=5,
>>> L
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
>>> L[:0]+=6,
>>> L
[6, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 10):

Use powers of the imaginary unit to calculate sines and cosines.

For example, given an angle `d` in degrees, you can calculate the sine and cosine as follows:

```python
p=1j**(d/90.)
s=p.real
c=p.imag
```

This can also be used for related functions such as the side length of a unit `n`-gon:

```python
l=abs(1-1j**(4./n))
```

Comment: Does... Does this also become a math golfing tip? o0

Answer (score 10):

### Combine assignments of reused values with unused for-loop variables

If you need to loop a number of times but you don't care about the iteration variable, you can co-opt the loop to assign a variable.

```python
r=reused;for _ in"_"*n:stuff
r=reused;exec("r;"*n)                          # [note 1]
r=reused;exec"r;"*n                            # [note 1]; Python 2 only
for r in[reused]*n:r

lambda args:((r:=reused)for _ in"_"*n)         # generally needs parentheses
lambda args,r=reused:(r for _ in"_"*n)         # only works with constants
lambda args:(r for r in[reused]*n)
```

This is generally a more versatile approach for assignment than the `:=` operator or using default arguments of functions, because it supports assigning to attributes `.x`, subscripts `[x]`, and unpacking with `*` or `,`.

```python
(stuff+(a[0]:=value)for _ in"_"*n)                   # syntax error
(stuff+a[0]for a[0]in[value]*n)                      # works, and shorter!

(stuff+a+b for*a,b in[value]*n)                      # works!
```

The only pitfall is that scope inside comprehensions is sometimes quite confusing, because the body of the comprehension is compiled as a separate implicit function.

[Taken from @xnor's use of it here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216302).

<sup>[note 1]: and longer if backslashes/quotes/newlines/... need to be escaped inside the string</sup>

---

*This is a bot account operated by pxeger. I'm posting this to get enough reputation to use chat.*

Comment: howdy there stranger! welcome to code gol...oh wait nevermind.

Answer (score 10):

## `0in` instead of `not all`

(or, under [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), `any(not ...)`)

```python
not all(...)
~-all(...)  # shorter than `not`, and with more forgiving precedence
0in(...)
```

```python
not all map(f,a)
0in map(f,a)  # the reduction is more significant here because you can omit the parentheses
```

This only works if the falsey values in the `...` sequence are actually `False` (or `0`/`0.0`/etc.) (**not** `[]`/`""`/`{}` etc.).

## `1in` instead of `any`

This one isn't shorter with a comprehension:

```python
any(f(x)for x in a)
1in(f(x)for x in a)
```

But it sometimes saves bytes with other kinds of expression by letting you omit the parentheses:

```python
any(map(f,a))
1in map(f,a)
```

This has a similar truthiness-related caveat to the above, though.

---

## Notes

These might sometimes have less favourable precedence, because they use the `in` operator. However, if you're combining this with a comparison you may be able to make additional use of [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60) about comparison condition chaining.

You can also use these if you want the entire `for`-comprehension in `any`/`all` to always be fully evaluated:

```python
any([... for x in a])
1in[... for x in a]
```

---

This one's rare, but if you need to evaluate and discard an extra expression for every item in a comprehension, you could use a dictionary here at no extra cost:

```python
1in[(condition,side_effect)[0]for x in a]
1in{condition:side_effect for x in a}
```

because `dict`'s `in` checks only the keys.

Answer (score 9):

Abuse the fact that in case of an expression yielding `True` boolean operators return the first value that decides about the outcome of the expression instead of a boolean:

```
>>> False or 5
5
```

is pretty straightforward. For a more complex example:

```
>>> i = i or j and "a" or ""
```

i's value remains unchanged if it already had a value set, becomes "a" if j has a value or in any other case becomes an empty string (which can usually be omitted, as i most likely already was an empty string).

Comment: Shorter: `i=i or j and"a"or""`

Answer (score 9):

### Check if a number is a power of 2

Check whether a positive integer `n` is a perfect power of 2, that is one of `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...`, with any of these expressions:

```python
n&~-n<1
n&-n==n
n^n-1>=n
2**n%n<1
```

The third expression also works for `n==0` giving `False`. The last is easy to modify to checking for, say, powers of 3.

Comment: `-n^n<-n` is also an option, even better if you're detecting a negative power of 2

Comment: oh, and as a modification of the second expression `-n&n^n` gives 0 for powers of 2, including zero.

Answer (score 8):

Lets play with some list tricks

```
a=[5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

can be written as:

```
a=[5]*7
```

It can be expanded in this way. Lets, say we need to do something like

```
for i in range(0,100,3):a[i]=5
```

Now using the slicing trick we can simply do:

```
a[0:100:3]=[5]*(1+99//3)
```

Comment: last example, of course, must be written `a[:100:3]=[5]*34`

Comment: @AMK yap i know ;) But i kept that way cause people may get hard time guessing how i got 34.
it just from the formula (1+(100-1)//3) where 100 is number of elements and 3 is the step.
Thanks for pointing it :D

Answer (score 8):

If you are doing something small in a for loop whose only purpose is to invoke a side effect (`pop`, `print` in Python 3, `append`), it might be possible to translate it to a list-comprehension. For example, from Keith Randall's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/40297/1), in the middle of a function, hence the indent:

```python
  if d>list('XXXXXXXXX'):
   for z in D:d.pop()
   c=['X']
```

Can be converted to:

```python
  if d>list('XXXXXXXXX'):
   [d.pop()for z in D]
   c=['X']
```

Which then allows this golf:

```python
  if d>list('XXXXXXXXX'):[d.pop()for z in D];c=['X']
```

An `if` within a `for` works just as well:

```python
for i in range(10):
 if is_prime(i):d.pop()
```

can be written as

```python
[d.pop()for i in range(10)if is_prime(i)]
```

Comment: `[d.pop()for i in range(10)if is_prime(i)]` is shorter as                                                             `for i in range(10):notprime(i)or d.pop()`, so it's shorter with a False condition instead of a True one if the condition can be squished into the `or`.

Obviously, if you need the popped values the comprehension is shorter, but this post is about side effects.

Answer (score 8):

### Use map for side effects

Usually you use `map` to transform a collection

```python
>> map(ord,"abc")
[97, 98, 99]
```

But you can also use it to repeatedly act on object by a built-in method that modifies it.

```python
>> L=[1,2,3,4,5]
>> map(L.remove,[4,2])
[None, None]
>> L
[1, 3, 5]
```

Be aware that the calls are done in order, so earlier ones might mess up later ones.

```python
>> L=[1,2,3,4,5]
>> map(L.pop,[0,1])
[1, 3]
>> L
[2, 4, 5]
```

Here, we intended to extract the first two elements of `L`, but after extracting the first, the next second element is the original third one. We could sort the indices in descending order to avoid this.

An advantage of the evaluation-as-action is that it can be done inside of a `lambda`. Be careful in Python 3 though, where `map` objects are not evaluated immediately. You might need an expression like `[*map(...)]` or `*map(...),` to force evaluation.

Comment: Or [`[*map(...)]`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzexQKOgKDOvRCfaUMdIxzhWUwEBlBXK8/PUSxTACrgMMvMUMJVzRWthCsb@/w8A).

Comment: Or [`*map(...),`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzexQKOgKDOvRCfaUMdIxzhWUwEBlBXK8/PUSxTACrgMMvMUMJVzRWthCsZyYRHU@f8fAA)

Answer (score 8):

### Logical short-circuiting in recursive functions

**A detailed guide**

I had worked with short-circuiting `and/or`'s for a while without really grasping how they work, just using `b and x or y` just as a template. I hope this detailed explanation will help you understand them and use them more flexibly.

---

Recursive named `lambda` functions are [often shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61526/20260) than programs that loop. For evaluation to terminate, there must be control flow to prevent a recursive call for the base case. Python has a [ternary condition operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) that fits the bill.

```python
f=lambda x:base_value if is_base_case else recursive_value
```

Note that [list selection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62/20260) won't work because Python evaluates both options. Also, regular `if _:` isn't an option because we're in a `lambda`.

---

Python has another option to short-circuit, the logical operator keywords `and` and `or`. The idea is that

```python
True or b == True
False and b == False
```

so Python can skip evaluate `b` in these cases because the result is known. Think of the evaluation of `a or b` as "Evaluate `a`. If it's True, output `a`. Otherwise, evaluate and output `b`." So, it's equivalent to write

```python
a or b
a if a else b
```

It's the same for `a or b` except we stop if `a` is False.

```python
a and b
a if (not a) else b
```

You might wonder why we didn't just write `False if (not a) else b`. The reason is that this works for non-Boolean `a`. Such values are [first converted to a Boolean](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html). The number `0`, `None`, and the empty list/tuple/set become `False`, and are so called "Falsey". The rest are "Truthy".

So, `a or b` and `a and b` always manages to produce either `a` or `b`, while forming a correct Boolean equation.

```python
(0 or 0) == 0
(0 or 3) == 3
(2 or 0) == 2
(2 or 3) == 2
(0 and 0) == 0
(0 and 3) == 0
(2 and 0) == 0
(2 and 3) == 3
('' or 3) == 3
([] and [1]) == []
([0] or [1]) == [0]
```

---

Now that we understand Boolean short-circuiting, let's use it in recursive functions.

```python
f=lambda x:base_value if is_base_case else recursive_value
```

The simplest and most common situation is when the base is something like `f("") = ""`, sending a Falsey value to itself. Here, it suffices to do `x and` with the argument.

For example, this function doubles each character in a string, `f("abc") == "aabbcc"`.

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0]*2+f(s[1:])
```

Or, this recursively sums the cubes of numbers `1 through n`, so `f(3)==36`.

```python
f=lambda n:n and n**3+f(n-1)
```

Another common situation is for your function to take non-negative numbers to lists, with a base case of `0` giving the empty list. We need to transform the number to a list while preserving Truthiness. One way is `n*[5]`, where the list can be anything nonempty. This seems silly, but it works.

So, the following returns the list `[1..n]`.

```python
f=lambda n:n*[5]and f(n-1)+[n]
```

Note that negative `n` will also give the empty list, which works here, but not always. For strings, it's similar with any non-empty string. If you've previously defined such a value, you can save chars by using it.

More generally, when your base value is an empty list, you can use the arithmetic values `True == 1` and `False == 0`  to do:

```python
[5]*(is_not_base_case)and ...
```

TODO: Truthy base value

---

TODO: `and/or`

Comment: An easy way to explain how `and` and `or` work might be:  
`x or y=if x:return x;return y`  
`x and y:if x:return y;return x`

Answer (score 7):

Cut out newlines wherever you can.

At the top-level, it doesn't matter.

```python
a=1
b=9
```

Takes the same amount of characters as:

```python
a=1;b=9
```

In the first case you have a newline instead of a `;`. But in function bodies, you save however deep the nesting level is:

```python
def f():
 a=1;b=9
```

Actually in this case, you can have them all on one line:

```python
def f():a=1;b=9
```

If you have an `if` or a `for`, you can likewise have everything on one line:

```python
if h:a=1;b=9
for g in(1,2):a=1;b=9
```

But if you have a nesting of control structures (e.g. `if` in a `for`, or `if` in a `def`), then you need the newline:

```python
if h:for g in(1,2):a=1;b=9 #ERROR

if h:
 for g in(1,2):a=1;b=9 # SAUL GOODMAN
```

Comment: You can use `a,b=1,9`

Comment: It's too bad you can't have multiple :s on one line :(

Comment: @OliverNi `a,b=1,9` does not save any bytes

Answer (score 7):

### Use eval to iterate

Say you want to apply `f` composed `k` times to the number `1`, then print the result.

This can be done via an `exec` loop,

```python
n=1
exec("n=f(n);"*k)
print(n)
```

which runs code like `n=1;n=f(n);n=f(n);n=f(n);n=f(n);n=f(n);print(n)`.

But, it's one character shorter to use `eval`

```python
print(eval("f("*k+'1'+")"*k))
```

which evaluates code like `f(f(f(f(f(1)))))` and prints the result.

This does not save chars in Python 2 though, where `exec` doesn't need parens but `eval` still does. It does still help though when `f(n)` is an expression in which `n` appears only once as the first or last character, letting you use only one string multiplication.

Answer (score 7):

One trick I have encountered concerns returning or printing Yes/No answers:

```
 print 'YNeos'[x::2]
```

x is the condition and can take value 0 or 1.

I found this rather brilliant.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! It seems that this is mostly a special case of [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/407/8478) though.

Answer (score 7):

A condition like

```
s = ''
if c:
    s = 'a'
```

can be written as

```
s = c*'a'
```

and there is possibly a need for parenthesis for condition.

This can also be combined with other conditions as (multiple ifs)

```
s = c1*'a' + c2*'b'
```

or (multiple elifs)

```
s = c1*'a' or c2*'b'
```

For example FizzBuzz problem's solution will be

```
for i in range(n):
    print((i%3<1)*"Fizz"+(i%5<1)*"Buzz" or i)
```

Answer (score 7):

## Use Splat (`*`) to pass a bunch of single character strings into a function

For example:

```
a.replace("a","b")
a.replace(*"ab")    -2 bytes

some_function("a","b","c")
some_function(*"abc")       -5 bytes
```

In fact, if you have `n` single-character strings, you will save `3(n - 1) - 1` or `3n - 4` bytes by doing this (because each time, you remove the `","` for each one and add a constant `*`).

Answer (score 7):

### Multiple **if** statements in comprehensions

If you need to keep multiple conditions inside comprehension, you can replace **and** with **if** to save a byte each time.

Works in Python 2 and 3.

```python
[a for a in 'abc'if cond1()and cond2()or cond3()and cond4()and cond5()]
[a for a in 'abc'if cond1()if cond2()or cond3()if cond4()if cond5()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZC9CgIxEIT7PMV20cLi/hpbQbCxshOLmOx5i7o5Yg706WMIGhTBlMPufDs748MPlusQDPagLZtqNl8KGB2xB7kaUJ@JT2lCnixDBQvYuQmlAId@cpyUeNvrgr2O9rW63D78SWZAUwA0P/flBtQV2HrAO@rJo5GZ1hZobSlOVwB0EbD9Ov0vlhB7Bb11oIDihjpqSbl2yg3GhVcVlN@gnOcQwhM)

Answer (score 7):

### Trig without imports

You can compute `cos` and `sin` without needing to `import math` by using complex arithmetic. For an angle of `d` degrees, its cosine is

```
(1j**(d/90)).real
```

and its sine is

```
(1j**(d/90)).imag
```

Here, `1j` is how Python writes the imaginary unit \$i\$. If your angle is `r` radians, you'll need to use `1j**(r/(pi/2))`, using a decimal approximation of `pi/2` if the challenge allows it.

If you're curious, this all works because of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

$$i^x = (e^{i \pi /2})^x = e^{i \pi /2 \cdot x} = \cos(\pi/2 \cdot x) + i \sin(\pi /2 \cdot  x)$$

Answer (score 7):

`!=` can be replaced with `-`
here is a example

```
n=int(input())
if n!=69:
 print("thanks for being mature")
```

instead of using `!=` you can use `-`
after that it should look like this

```
n=int(input())
if n-69:
 print("thanks for being mature")
```

Answer (score 6):

List comprehension.

```python
shortList = []
for x in range(10):
    shortList += [x * 2]
```

can be shortened into

```python
shortList = [x*2 for x in range(10)]
```

Or even shorter:

```python
shortList = range(0,20,2)
```

Comment: Can even be shortened (by a character) to `[x**2for x in range(10)]`

Comment: @Haidro I think you mean `[x*2for x in range(10)]`

Comment: @Timtech You are right :)

Comment: Note that the final trick works only in Python 2. In Python 3 you must use `shortList = list(range(0, 20, 2))`

Comment: @UndoneStudios: `*shortList,=range(0,20,2)` or as an expression, `[*range(0,20,2)]` will make it a `list` with fewer characters than calling `list()` (constructor call adds six, `[*...]` adds three over just `range(0,20,2)`, and `*shortList,=range(0,20,2)` only adds two).

Comment: Yeah. What I want to point out is that range is no longer a list, so conversions to lists are necessary

Comment: @UndoneStudios: Although if you don't need a *`list`*, just a sequence/iterable of the numbers, `range` alone works fine; it implements the full sequence protocol (aside from concatenation and multiplication), so you can index, slice, iterate, etc. without converting at all, depending on use case.

Answer (score 6):

### Build a string instead of joining

To concatenate strings or characters, it can be shorter to repeatedly append to the empty string than to `join`.

**23 chars**

```python
s=""
for x in l:s+=f(x)
```

**25 chars**

```python
s="".join(f(x)for x in l)
```

Assume here that `f(x)` stands for some expression in `x`, so you can't just `map`.

But, the `join` may be shorter if the result doesn't need saving to a variable or if the `for` takes newlines or indentation.

Answer (score 6):

## String keys to dicts

For a dictionary with string keys which also happen to be valid Python variable names, you can get a saving if there's at least three items by using `dict`'s keyword arguments:

```py
{'a':1,'e':4,'i':9}
dict(a=1,e=4,i=9)
```

The more string keys you have, the more quote characters you'll save, so this is particularly beneficial for large dictionaries (e.g. for a kolmogorov challenge).

Answer (score 6):

When squaring single letter variables, it is shorter to times it by itself

```
>>> x=30
>>> x*x
900
```

Is one byte shorter than

```
>>> x=30
>>> x**2
900
```

Answer (score 6):

### Iterate over adjacent pairs

It's common to want to iterate over adjacent pairs of items in a list or string, i.e.

```python
"golf" -> [('g','o'), ('o','l'), ('l','f')]
```

There's a few methods, and which is shortest depends on specifics.

**Shift and zip**

```python
## 47 bytes
l=input()
for x,y in zip(l,l[1:]):do_stuff(x,y)
```

Create a list of adjacent pairs, by removing the first element and zipping the original with the result. This is most useful in a list comprehension like

```python
sum(abs(x-y)for x,y in zip(l,l[1:]))
```

You can also use `map` with a two-input function, though note that the original list is no longer truncated.

```python
## Python 2
map(cmp,l[:-1],l[1:])
```

**Keep the previous**

```python
## 41 bytes, Python 3
x,*l=input()
for y in l:do_stuff(x,y);x=y
```

Iterate over the elements of the list, remembering the element from a previous loop. This works best with Python 3's ability to unpack to input into the initial and remaining elements.

If there's an initial value of `x` that serves as a null operation in `do_stuff(x,y)`, you can iterate over the whole list.

```python
## 39 bytes
x=''
for y in input():do_stuff(x,y);x=y
```

**Truncate from the front**

```python
## 46 bytes
l=input()
while l[1:]:do_stuff(*l[:2]);l=l[1:]
```

Keep shortening the list and act on the first two elements. This works best when your operation is better-expressed on a length-two list or string than on two values.

---

I've written these all as loops, but they also lend to a recursive functions. You can also adjust to get cyclic pairs by putting the first element at the end of the list, or as the initial previous-value.

---

The Python 3.8 "walrus" [assignment expressions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180041/20260) allow a short expression to give pairs, though with an extra initial element.

```python
>>> p=''
>>> [(p,p:=c)for c in"golf"]
[('', 'g'), ('g', 'o'), ('o', 'l'), ('l', 'f')]
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning since I just used it, if you want the "initial value of `x` that serves as a null operation" at the end of your list as well so the final item is processed with it you can do `x=''(\n)for y in*input(),x:do_stuff(x,y);x=y`

Comment: As of 3.10, if you already have `itertools` stuff imported for some other reason with `from itertools import*`, you can use `pairwise` for this, replacing `for x,y in zip(l,l[1:]):` with `for x,y in pairwise(l):` to save a character. Also, on your "Truncate from the front" solution, you can shave a byte by using unpacking and a single indexing operation in place of two uses of slicing: `while l[1:]:a,*l=l;do_stuff(a,l[0])`

Answer (score 6):

When mapping a function on a list in Python 3, instead of doing `[f(x)for x in l]` or `list(map(f,l))`, do `[*map(f,l)]`.

It works for all other functions returning generators too (like `filter`).

The best solution is still switching to Python 2 though

Answer (score 6):

## Long function names

Here's a trick to shorten long function names. The basic idea is to fetch the name by using `dir()`. This would return the name as a string, so we must follow it with an `eval` to make it usable. Below is an exaggerated example from the `itertools` module:

```py
from itertools import*

combinations_with_replacement('ABC',2)
eval(dir()[7])('ABC',2)
```

In the minimal case, if the function name is 15 bytes or longer, there's a *chance* that it can still save bytes. This is assuming, that the name can be accessed by `dir` with a single-digit index:

```py
???????????????()
eval(dir()[?])()
```

Comment: In your example, there are two unmatched parantheses.

Comment: @orthoplex Oh oops, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 6):

### Use the walrus operator `:=` in list comprehension to store the previous value of the iterable

Instead of the convoluted

```
f=[s[i]for i in range(len(s))if s[i-1]!=s[i]]
```

You can use

```
e=""
f=[c for c in s if e!=(e:=c)]
```

Which saves 11 bytes in this example. Care needs to be taken that `e` is reassigned after being evaluted. It also needs to be initialised before the list, which is quite easy to do with default function arguments

Answer (score 5):

Be aware of [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
if isdigit(a) and isdigit(b) and isdigit(c)
if all(map(isdigit,[a,b,c]))
```

Comment: `filter(function, iterable) returns a list of all the elements of `iterable` for which `function` is a `True`-y value and a non-empty list is `True`-y, so this can be shortened further to `if filter(isdigit,[a,b,c])`

Comment: Over a year later, I'm reading this thread again and I'm embarrassed about my previous comment. `if filter(isdigit,[a,b,c])` is **not** equivalent to the code in the answer; but it would be if @moose used `isdigit(a) or...` and `if any(...`.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you need convert boolean expression into integer (0/1)
Simple use this Boolean (in examples below `c > 0`) in ariphmetic

```
a=b+(c>0)
a+=c>0
a=sum(c>0 for c in b) # space in "0 for" may be omitted
```

And sometimes you need simple convert boolean to int (for example for printing or convert to binary string). In programm you may use some variants

```
1 if c>0 else 0
c>0and 1or 0
(0,1)[c>0]
int(c>0)
```

but shortest way is

```
+(c>0)
```

Comment: I find `+c` being shorter. E.g. let `c` be a boolean, then `4+c` is 5 if `c` is True else 4.

Answer (score 5):

Abusing `try`/`except` blocks can sometimes save characters, especially for exiting out of nested loops or list comprehensions.  This:

```python
for c in s:
 for i in l:
  q=ord(c)==i
  if q:print i,c;break
 if q:break
```

... can become this, saving 3 characters:

```python
try:
 for c in s:
  for i in l:
   if ord(c)==i:print i,c;1/0
except:0
```

... which in this particular instance can be compressed even further using list comprehensions:

```python
try:[1/(ord(c)-i)for c in s for i in l]
except:print i,c
```

For an example, see e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36492/16766.

Answer (score 5):

When using Python 3, for your final print statement, use `exit` to save one char (note: this prints to STDERR, so you might not be able to use this):

```python
print('x')
exit('x')
```

`exit` even adds a trailing newline. There is one caveat, however: `exit(some_integer)` will not print.

Comment: Does this print to STDOUT or STDERR? This sounds like it would be the latter, but in most challenges only the former is allowed.

Comment: @Sp3000 I don't know... how can I tell?

Comment: Seems to be [stderr](http://ideone.com/OGXBjR)

Comment: `exit(some_integer)` is valid because exit code is a default output form.

Answer (score 5):

## Take multi-line input

Use `list(iter(input,eof))` to take multi-line input. `eof` can be any string that you want to stop taking input on if you see it. An example would be `eof = ''`. The python 2 version is `list(iter(raw_input,eof))`, however you may want to use `sys.stdin.readlines()` instead if you have already imported `sys`.

Comment: `list(iter(input,eof))` is shorter by one, you don't need that space. Also worth noting that this is only for Python 3 - Python 2 is 4 bytes longer because `raw_input`.

Comment: Is shorter than what?

Comment: Than what you have posted, because it has an extraneous space.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assume the reader would remove the space though. I will edit it out now.

Comment: `read(0)` returns an iterable of all lines of input on many systems (in Python 3.9, not sure when it was added).

Comment: If you're using Py3 anyway, `*s,=iter(input,eof)` is shorter than `list(iter(input,eof))` and gives you a named variable. On 3.5+, `[*iter(input,eof)]` (as unnamed expression) shaves three characters off any place you'd otherwise call `list`. `sys.stdin.readlines()` is *never* useful though, because listifying `sys.stdin` in one of these ways is always going to be shorter (with `list(sys.stdin)`, `[*sys.stdin]`, or `*s,=sys.stdin`). `.readlines()` is a garbage API that should have been dropped from Py3; even outside Code Golf, direct iteration is usually better.

Answer (score 5):

## Use slicing + assignment instead of mutator methods

```
l.insert(x,y) # before
l[x:x]=y,     # after

l.reverse()   # before
l[::-1]=l     # after

l.append(x)   # before
l[L:]=x,      # after (where L is any integer >= len(l))

l[:]=x        # set the contents of l to the contents of x
```

**EDIT**: thanks to @quintopia for pointing this out, these are *statements*, not *expressions*. The mutator methods are void functions, so they are expressions which evaluate to `None`. This means that things like `[l.reverse() for x in L]` and `condition or l.reverse()` are valid, whereas `[l[::-1]=l for x in L]` and `condition or l[::-1]=l` are not.

Comment: Note that this cannot always be done. For instance, when using `or` or `and` as conditionals, assignment is not allowed, but `append` and the like are.

Comment: `l[:]=x` is a bit unpythonic - same number of bytes, but I reckon `l=x[:]` is better practice. Also, `[::-1]` is listed as a tip [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15683/21487), [`L[:x]+=y,`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52639/21487) is better for the general case where `x` might be an expression (but same byte count if it's just `x`), and `l+=x,` is listed [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12877/21487) for append.

Comment: @Sp3000 `l[:]=x` and `l=x[:]` do different things. The former mutates the list itself, i.e. all references to that list, whereas the latter sets the *variable* l to a copy of x

Comment: @Cyoce Oh, nevermind then - my eyes are going to have to get used to seeing that :P

Comment: l+=[x] is shorter than l[L:]=x,

Answer (score 5):

### Find the n'th number meeting a condition

Many sequence challenges ask you to find the n'th number in a sequence of increasing positive integers. When you have a expression `p(i)` that checks membership, you can do this with the recursive function:

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n and-~f(n-p(i),i+1)
```

Note that expression `p(i)` must give 0 or 1, not just Falsey or Truthy. The outputs are one-indexed, so say for the sequence of primes, it would give

```python
f(1) = 2
f(2) = 3
...
```

For 0-indexed outputs, shift the base case

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n+1and-~f(n-p(i),i+1)
```

The recursive function `f=lambda n,i=1:n and-~f(n-p(i),i+1)` works by decrementing the required count `n` each time it gets a hit, and incrementing the output value each time for each value it checks. It might seem weird to redundantly track `i`, but it's longer to do:

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n and f(n-p(i),i+1)or~-i
```

Also compare the natural list strategy (zero-indexed here)

```python
lambda n:[i for i in range(n*n)if p(i)][n]
```

(You might need a larger bound than `n*n`.)

Answer (score 5):

Format() works on dates:

```
"We are in year: %s" % (date.strftime('%y'))
```

Becomes:

```
"We are in year: {:%y}".format(date)
```

Or even better with f-strings:

```
f"We are in year: {date:%y}"
```

Answer (score 5):

### Difference of two parallel expressions

Say you have a challenge to find the difference of some characteristic on two inputs. Your solution has the form `lambda a,b:e(b)-e(a)`, where `e` is some long expression you've written. Repeating `e` twice is wasteful, so what do you do?

Here are templates sorted by length. Assume that `e` stands for a long expression, not one that's already defined as a function. Also assume inputs can be taken in either order.

[**31 bytes***](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfapuTmJuUkqhQYVWhVcGVZhvzHyKglWOVWpaYo6GeqqFarKmrrmWkmqOtbqCu@b@gKDOvRCFNw0THWPM/AA)

```python
lambda*l:eval('e(%s)-'*2%l+'0')
```

*Requires that `e` only mentions its variable once. Assumes `-e(x)` negates the whole expression, otherwise requires parens like `-(e(x))` for two more bytes.

[**34 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfapuTmJuUkqhQYVWhVfE/DcZN1NFKskrVSNTU1Uiy09BMzEtRSNPQStLU/F9QlJlXAuSY6Bhr/gcA)

```python
f=lambda a,*b:e(a)-(b>()and f(*b))
```

[**36 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfapuTmJuUkqhQYVWhVcGVZhvzHyqQqJNklaKRpKmbopGoyZWCUJeqUaH5v6AoM69EIU3DWMdE8z8A)

```python
lambda a,b:d(b)-d(a)
d=lambda x:e(x)
```

[**36 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfapuTmJuUkqhQYVWhVfE/USfJNjpVo0IzLb9IoUIhMw@ICkpLNDRjuQqKMvNKFJJ0E///N9YxAQA)

```python
a,b=[e(x)for x in input()]
print b-a
```

[**37 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfapuTmJuUkqhQYVWhVfG/yNaAKy2/SKFCITMPiApKSzQ0rYpsUzUqNHWLuAqKMvNKFIr@/zfWMQEA)

```python
r=0
for x in input():r=e(x)-r
print r
```

[**39 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfapuTmJuUkqhQYVWhVcGVZhvzHyKglWOVmVeiFx9fXJoUH6@hFZ2qUaGZll@kUKGQmaeQE6v5v6AIqEAhTcNEx1jzPwA)

```python
lambda*l:int.__sub__(*[e(x)for x in l])
```

Answer (score 5):

## Formatting a Matrix

I've seen this code to get a character matrix (2D array) as a string.

```
'\n'.join(''.join(i)for i in M)
```

It's shorter to use a `map` instead:

```
'\n'.join(map(''.join,M))
```

If you're printing the result, it's shortest to use a `for` loop:

```
print('\n'.join(map(''.join,M)))
for i in M:print(*i,sep='')      # -5 bytes
```

If you're using Python 2, you can't use the `print` trick, but you can still use the `for` loop:

```
for i in M:print(''.join(i))     # -3 bytes
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python,

```python
True == 1   # true
False == 0  # true
```

So,

```python
(a<b)*2-1
```

returns 1 if b is larger than a. If not, returns -1.

More golfing,

```python
-(a>b)|1
```

returns exactly same value as mentioned above.

Useful when modify iterator index by comparable values.

Comment: `a<b or-1` also works

Answer (score 5):

### Math built-ins in 3.8

In addition to the famous [walrus operator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180041/20260), Python 3.8 introduces useful new math features.

**Modular inverse**

The modular-power built-in [`pow(base, exp, mod)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) can now compute the modular inverse using `exp=-1`. This requires that `base` and `mod` are relatively prime integers.

```python
>>> pow(38, -1, 97)
23
>>> 23 * 38 % 97 == 1
True
```

`exp` may be any negative integer, which lets you compute modular powers of the modular inverse.

---

The [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) library has useful new functions for combinatorics and distances. Access them with `import math`. Or, write `from math import*` to import them without the `math.`, which is worth it if you write more than one call.

**Combinatorics**

- [`math.comb(n,k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb): The binomial coefficient `n choose k`, which equals `n! / (k! * (n - k)!)`.
- [`math.perm(n,k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.perm): The number of ordered choices of `k` elements from `n`, which is `n! / (n - k)!`. Calling just `math.perm(n)` gives `n!`, useful as a synonym for `math.factorial(n)`.
- [`math.prod(l)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod): The product of the elements of a list or iterable `l`, analogous to `sum`.

**Distances and square roots**

- [`math.dist(p,q)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.dist): The Euclidean distance between two points `p` and `q`. The inputs `p` and `q` must be lists or iterables that are the same length.
- [`math.hypot(*p)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot): The Euclidean distance from a point `p` to zero. Now takes any number of arguments; before it took only two. For some reason, arguments still must be splatted like `math.hypot(1,2,3)` rather than `math.hypot([1,2,3])`.
- [`math.isqrt(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt): The integer square root, that is the floor of the square root of `n`. Requires than `n` is a non-negative integer. Usually `n**.5//1` suffices instead, but this gives exact integer output rather than a float.

Answer (score 5):

## Using `exec` to remove repeated  `print`

This is not quite often applicable, but can save some bytes, especially in ASCII art. Take the following code, which prints the flag where `n=4`.

```python
# 43 bytes                  |  ***
n=input()                   |  **
while~-n:n-=1;print'*'*n    |  *
print'|'                    |  |
```

Notice that we repeat `print` twice. We can remove this using `exec` in the following code, saving 3 bytes.

```python
# 40 bytes
n=input()
exec"'*'*n;n-=1;print"*n+"'|'"
```

Answer (score 5):

## Printing the elements of a list, with spaces

[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

Suppose we have to print a list as a string *with spaces*, like square of numbers upto `10`. Then,

[Instead of](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ11BXS8rPzNPo7ikSCNTS8tIMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BQU1Pz/38A),

```python
print(' '.join(str(i**2)for i in range(11))) # 44 chars
```

[We can do](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ0sjU0vLKC2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BQU1Pz/38A),

```python
print(*(i**2for i in range(11))) # 32 chars
```

Answer (score 5):

### Special characters in string literals

When you write a quoted literal string in your code, perhaps to compress a big blob of data, certain characters must be replaced by a two-character escape sequence.

**Null byte `\0` (ASCII 0)**

The null byte can't be present verbatim in Python code. Write it as `\0`.

**Newline `\n` (ASCII 10)**

An actual newline `\n` can't appear in a string literal because the Python lexer will read it and think the line has ended without closing the initial quote. But, a triple-quoted string like `'''stuff'''` or `"""stuff"""` may contain newlines. This saves bytes with 5+ newlines, which can be useful in ASCII art.

**Carriage return `\r` (ASCII 13)**

A carriage return always needs escaping as `\r`. Though allowed in a triple-quoted string, a literal `\r` is misread as a newline `\n`.

**Quotes `"` (ASCII 34) and `'` (ASCII 39)**

A single-quoted string can contain double quotes like `'"'`, but must escape single-quotes like `'\''`, and vice-versa for double-quoted strings. Choose whichever option leads to less escaping.

A triple-quoted string is OK with unescaped quotes of the same type like `'''it's'''`. But, having quotes at the start and end or three-in-a-row can confuse the lexer into giving a SyntaxError.

**Backslash `\` (ASCII 92)**

A backslash can be escaped as `\\`. But, Python allows just writing `\` if it's followed by a character that can't make it an escape sequence. This is any character not in `abfnrtvx0123456789"'\` or literal newline `\n`.

You can use a `r`-prefixed raw string like `r'\n'` to ignore most escape sequences, so `r'\n'` is just a backslash followed by a letter `n` and `r'\\'` is two backslashes. Quote characters still get escaped but don't consume the backslash, so `r'\''` is backslash then single-quote. This can cause complications: `r'\'`, `r'\\\'`, and `r'\\''` all give SyntaxError.

---

For reference, the special characters are ASCII values `[0, 10, 13, 39, 34, 92]`. When doing compression, you might tweak your method to avoid hitting these values.

Some weird characters can be written verbatim without escaping, such as:

- bell `\a` (ASCII 7)
- backspace `\b` (ASCII 8)
- tab `\t` (ASCII 9)
- vertical tab (ASCII 11)
- form feed `\f` (ASCII 12)
- DEL (ASCII 127)

StackExchange posts won't render these, but Python clients and [TIO](https://tio.run/#python2) should handle them fine. [Here they are for copy-pasting.](https://tio.run/##TY3RCoJAEEUfq8mPuAwIRfuiPVhCXxKx6LqStKmsEvTUp2@uaThPM4c797Tv/t7UsXO5NkYmGOcCXjHlmXp0baa0PHmyZuqzXJ7xz2yYXtKzKJrIlqls7LPUupBR7EnAARXaDFcyv32YyAzL9acUWIgERofAXCywLBSYum7eA4WqhknR2qruweGxSxkhGlvs1B4HKOe@)

Characters with ASCII codes 128 and up can't be included in Python 2 code without a extra line declaring an encoding [like this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Xzk1Lzk/JTMv3aq0JI2roCgzr0RB6fAqpf//AQ). Python 3, though, [handles them fine](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ@nwKiVNLij70doJSpr//wMA), including multibyte Unicode characters.

Answer (score 5):

## Shorten `while 1`

It is possible to shorten a `while 1:` by replacing the `1` with an existing expression inside of the loop body. Common ways to make use of this in Python 3 include embedding

- a `print()` statement:

```py
while 1:print(x);...
# vs
while[print(x)]:...
```

- a chained expression:

```py
while 1:x>1==print(x);...
# vs
while[x>1==print(x)]:...
```

- a walrus operator (Python 3.8 and above):

```py
while 1:x=1;...
while x:=1:...
```

In general, any expression (one that returns a value), can be used as the `while` condition to save a byte or two. Often it's necessary to wrap the expression in `[]` to ensure it maintains a truthy value.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to import a lot of modules you can reassign `__import__` to something shorter, this also has the advantage of being able to name imports anything you want.

```
i=__import__;s=i('string');x=i('itertools');
```

Comment: I've rarely found this to be actually useful. Generally `import string,itertools`, `import string,itertools as M`, `from itertools import*` and other variants tend to be shorter...

Comment: `s,i=map(__import__,['string','itertools'])` is shorter than your example, but still longer than `import string as s,itertools as i`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista: The `map` approach does scale better if you are using a single space-separated string and splitting it. But to pull ahead of the alternatives, you'd need a *lot* of imports. As in `s,i,c,p,f,b,d=map(__import__,'string itertools collections subprocess fractions bisect datetime'.split())`. So probably not useful in most golfing scenarios. :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Avoid the `repeat` argument of `itertools.product`

As @T.Verron points out, in most cases (e.g. ranges and lists), you can instead do

```
product(*[x]*n)
```

However, even if you have a generator which you can only use once, like a Python 3 `map`, the `repeat` argument is still unnecessary. In such a case you can use `itertools.tee`:

```
product(x,repeat=n)
product(*tee(x,n))
```

For `n = 2` you don't even need to include `n`, since 2 is the default argument to `tee`.

Comment: `product(*[L]*n)` is even shorter.

Comment: @T.Verron The initial use case I had in mind was something like a Python 3 `map`, for which that wouldn't work, but I'll add it as a note thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't feersum have an [open 500-point bounty](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5603/39328) for using itertools at all in a sufficiently old question?

Answer (score 4):

## Alternatives to builtin string functions

#### str.capitalize for single words

Use `str.title` instead for single words. The difference between the two functions is that `capitalize` only capitalises the first word, while `title` capitalises all words:

```py
>>> "the quick brown fox".capitalize()
'The quick brown fox'
>>> "the quick brown fox".title()
'The Quick Brown Fox'
```

#### str.index

`str.find` is almost always better, and even returns -1 if the substring is not present rather than throwing an exception.

#### str.startswith

See [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51783/21487) by @xnor.

#### str.splitlines

`str.split` is shorter:

```py
s.splitlines()
s.split('\n')
```

However, `str.splitlines` may be useful if you need to preserve trailing newlines, which can be done by passing `1` as the `keepends` argument.

Comment: `splitlines` also avoids a trailing blank line when the string ends in a newline. `'foo\nbar\n'.split('\n')` produces `['foo', 'bar', '']` (len 3, with trailing empty string), while `'foo\nbar\n'.splitlines()` produces `['foo', 'bar']` (len 2, no trailing empty string), which can save trouble in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

### Dictionary defaults as entries

Say you have an dictionary literal, which I'll denote `{...}`, and you want to get the value for a key `k`, with a default of `d` if `k` is missing.

You can save two bytes by prepending an entry rather than using `get`

```python
{k:d,...}[k]
{...}.get(k,d)
```

Because later entries override earlier ones of the same key, the entry `k:d` gets overwritten if it appears in the dict, but remains if key `k` isn't present.

Note that this required writing `k` twice, which is fine for a variable, but poor when `k` is an expression.

Answer (score 4):

**Access list, while building it inside comprehension**

In python version 2.4 (and <2.3 with some tweaks) it is possible to access list, from list comprehension. [Source #1](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204297/),  [Source #2 (Safari, Python Cookbook, 2nd edition)](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch16s11.html)

Python creates secret name `_[1]` for list, while it is created and store it in `locals`. Also names `_[2]`, `_[3]`... are used for nested lists.

So to access list, you may use `locals()['_[1]']`.

In earlier versions this is not enough. You'll need to use `locals()['_[1]'].__self__`

I couldn't find evidence, that somethins like that is possible in versions >2.4

Don't think, that it might be usefull often, but who knows! At least it helps with building one-liners.

Example:

```
# Remove duplicates from a list:
>>> L = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
>>> [x for x in L if x not in locals()['_[1]']]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: This still exists in later Pythons. In Python 3, it's called `'.0'`, and it's a generator.

Answer (score 4):

If transforming from list to a tuple or set to a set, list or tuple is needed, as of Python 3.5 you can use the splat operator:

```
tuple(iterable) -> (*iterable,)  (-3 bytes)
set(iterable)   -> {*iterable}   (-2 bytes)
list(iterable)  -> [*iterable]   (-3 bytes)
```

If you're doing this as well as appending/prepending, you can do the following for an extra bonus:

```
iterable+[1]       -> *iterable,1          (-2 bytes, 3 for tuples)
iterable+iter2     -> *iterable,*iterable2 (+1 byte, 0 for tuples, though can combine types)
[1]+iterable+[1]   -> 1,*iterable,1        (-3 bytes, -4 for tuples)
iterable+[1]+iter2 -> *iterable,1,*iter2   (0 bytes, -1 for tuples)
```

Basically, `,*` instead of `,` gives a +1 byte penalty and `,` instead of `,[]` gives -2 bytes.

This shows `[1,*iterable,1]` is a golfier way of doing `[1]+iterable+[1]` by one byte, even when we're not doing any type conversion.

And just for fun, `{*{}}` is the same length as `set()` for challenges without letters.

Comment: The last one can also be useful if there is a letter preceding `set()` (e.g. ...`and set()` can become ...`and{*{}}`). Oh, and it can be replaced with `{*()}` or `{*[]}` if an empty `dict` feels unsettling. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Shorter way to copy/clone a list

(not deep clone. For deep clone see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51022/69850))

(credit to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137890/69850))

```
a=x[:]
b=[*x]
c=x*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fYRttqGOkYxz7P9G2ItoqlivJNlqrIpYr2bZCy/B/SmqOAli0oCgzr0SjQidRJ0knWfM/AA)

Comment: Alternative in Python 3 which can be shorter when combined with other assignments: `*d,=x`

Answer (score 4):

### Replace `not` with `1-`

In python, the negation operator `not` wastes bytes, so we have to find a shorter way. Negation can be implemented as subtraction from 1 (obtained from my Keg experiece), which saves 1 byte. (Also, `True` and `False` can be alternatively represented as `1` and `0` internally, so this will not matter much.)

Compare [this program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190892/bot-problem-how-to-solve-this-problem#190892):

```
lambda s:not(s[0]+s[-1]).isdigit()
```

With this program:

```
lambda s:1-(s[0]+s[-1]).isdigit()
```

Some straightforward tricks that might help:

```
and -> *
or -> +
```

Comment: These answers show some other ways to manipulate boolean variables: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66574/88506 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40795/88506

Answer (score 4):

## `dict.get` as a first-class function

```py
# all keys in the dict G with a truthy value
[k for k in G if G[k]]
filter(G.get,G)

# all keys in the dict G with a falsy value
[k for k in G if not G[k]]
G.keys()-filter(G.get,G)
```

## `{…,**d}` or `a|b` to merge `dict`s in Python

```py
# merge two dicts
a={…}
b={…}
# Python <3.9
merged={**a,**b} # the order lets you decide which overrides which
# Python ≥3.9
merged=a|b

# set a defaut value
G.setdefault(a,1)
G[a]=G.get(a,1)
# Python <3.9
G={a:1,**G} 
# Python ≥3.9
G={a:1}|G
```

## Extract elements from a list using `::`

```py
# This is a very specific tip when you want to get both an element at
# the near beginning of a list and one somewhere near the end.
# For example, let's assume you want to take the elements at indices i=6 and j=37
# from a list L of length l=40 (it works only if i+j*2<l)

# ok
a=L[5];b=L[36]
# equivalent
a,b=L[5],L[36]
# 36 = 5 + 31
a,b=L[5::31]
```

## Set literals

`set()` is 5 chars just to create an empty set. If you can have an initial element `e`, you can save 2 chars with `{e}`.

## Generators instead of comprehension lists in function calls

```py
# assuming the function iterates on its argument
f([x**2 for x in range(4)])
f(x**2 for x in range(4))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Access static methods on instances

If you're accessing a static method or class method, for example `int.from_bytes` or `dict.fromkeys`, you can also still access them on instances of that class - it doesn't have to be on the class itself. It's very often shorter to do this:

```
int.from_bytes(...
0 .from_bytes(...

dict.fromkeys(...
{}.fromkeys(...
```

Often you already have an instance of that class stored in a one-letter variable, so it can be even shorter:

```
x.from_bytes
```

It doesn't matter what value `x` is, and it isn't changed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list checking instead of using `or`s in a clause statement.

e.g. instead of using

```python
if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 or i % 7 == 0 ...:
# Golfed:
if i%3==0or i%5==0or i%7==0 ...:
```

use

```python
if 0 in [i % 3, i % 5, i % 7, ...]:
# Golfed:
if 0in[i%3,i%5,i%7,...]:
```

This saves around `2-3` characters per condition, but can only be used in certain circumstances.

Comment: I used this tip [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251568/110681)

Answer (score 4):

## Instead of `not in`, use `in` with `^1` or `1-`

Often, it helps to replace `a not in b` with `(a in b)^1`. By themselves,it doesn't save any bytes, but it often means that you can remove whitespace:

For example, `if a not in b:` can just be `if(a in b)^1:` to save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## Long numbers to `1e_`

I'm not sure if this has been mentioned before (likely), so either I'm going crazy or I'm blind.

Long numbers like `10000` can be written as `1e4` for short. Do note that using `1e_` gives a decimal, **not** a integer, so `1e4` in fact gives `10000.0`, so be wary when  doing stuff like:

```
for x in range(1,1e4):print(x%5)
```

which gives an error since when using `range` you have to use integers.

Comment: I think the reason it gives an error is because of the fact that `range` requires `ints` and not `float`s, and it's not because of the modulo.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can use Python's `exec`-statement combined with string repetition, to shorten loops. Unfortunately, you can't often use this, but when you can you can get rid of a lot of long loop constructs. Additionally, because `exec` is a statement you can't use it in lambdas, but `eval()` might work (but `eval()` is quite restricted in what you can do with it) although it's 2 characters longer.

Here is an example of this technique in use: [GCJ 2010 1B-A Codegolf Python Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892126/file-fix-it-codegolf-gcj-2010-1b-a/2892339#2892339)

Comment: What kind of restrictions are you thinking about? I don't think Python in itself has any kind of restriction on exec, so you must be referring to problem statements?

Comment: @hallvabo, you're right it's `eval()` I was most likely thinking of. You can't do `eval("print 1")` because `print 1` is a statement. I'll update the post.

Comment: As a general rule, this is worth trying when you need to do something n times, but don't care about the index. As soon as you need to initialise a loop variable and increment it, it ends up slightly longer than a for loop

Comment: Also used in my GCJ 2009 1B-A Solution. nested exec's and evals (4 in total) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433263/code-golf-decision-tree/1436664

Comment: In Python 3 you can do `eval("print(1)")` since `print()` is now a function.

Comment: In Python 3 you can also do `exec("print(1)")` since `exec()` is now a function.

Answer (score 3):

Was somewhat mentioned but I want to expand:

```
[a,b],[c,d]=[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

works as well as simple a,b=[1,2]. Another great thing is to use ternary operator (similiar to C-like ?:)

```
x if x<3 else y
```

and no one mentioned map. Map will call first function given as first argument on each item from second argument. For example assume that a is a list of strings of integers (from user input for example):

```
sum(map(int,a))
```

will make sum of all integers.

Comment: Quoting the OP: *Please post one tip per answer.*

Comment: `x if cond else y`  == `cond and x or y`.

Answer (score 3):

When your program needs to return a value, you might be able to use a `yield`, saving one character:

```python
def a(b):yield b
```

However, to print it you'd need to do something like

```python
for i in a(b):print i
```

Comment: If only a single value is yielded, `print next(i())` will work too.

Comment: Or just do `print[*a(b)]`

Answer (score 3):

If you rely on data (mostly for kolmogorov-complexity problems), use the built-in zip encoding/decoding and store the data in a file (add +1 for the filename):

```
open('f','rb').read().decode('zip')
```

If you have to store the data in the source code, then you need to encode the zip with base64 and do:

```
"base64literal".decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

These don't necessarily save characters in all instances, though.

Answer (score 3):

### **Easiest way to swap two values**

```
>>> a=5
>>> b=4
>>> a,b=b,a
>>> a
4
>>> b
5
```

Answer (score 3):

## Shorter isinstance

Instead of

```
isinstance(x,C) # 15 bytes
```

there are several alternatives:

```
x.__class__==C  # 14 bytes
'a'in dir(x)    # 12 bytes, if the class has a distinguishing attribute 'a'
type(x)==C      # 10 bytes, doesn't work with old-style classes
'K'in`x`        # 8 bytes, only in python 2, if no other classes contain 'K'
                # watch out for false positives from the hex address
```

Some of them may save extra bytes depending on the context, because you can eliminate a space before or after the expression.

Thanks Sp3000 for contributing a couple of tips.

Answer (score 3):

### Use IDLE 3.3 to take multiline input

In IDLE versions 3.1 to 3.3, the command `input()` reads an entire multiline string like `"line1\nline2"`, rather than a single line at a time as per [the spec](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input). This was [fixed in version 3.4](http://bugs.python.org/issue20058).

Calling `input()` only once is very convenient for golfing. Whether one can take advantage of this is debatable, but I think it is an acceptable [interpreter- or environment-specific behavior](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5852/20260).

Comment: Wait... so how do you... sort of, enter the string if Enter adds a newline rather than EOF? Does CTRL+D work on Windows?

Comment: @tac I copy-paste it into IDLE.

Answer (score 3):

### Optional empty sequence argument

Suppose we want to write a recursive function that prepends to a sequence (e.g. list, tuple) each time. For example, the Python 3 program

```py
def f(n,k,L=[]):n and[f(n-1,k,[b]+L)for b in range(k)]or print(L)
```

works like `itertools.product`, taking `n,k` and printing all length `n` lists of numbers  taken from `range(k)`. *(Example thanks to @xnor)*

If we don't need `L` to be a list specifically, we can save on the optional empty list argument by making use of unpacking, like so:

```py
def f(n,k,*T):n and[f(n-1,k,b,*T)for b in range(k)]or print(T)
```

where `T` is now a tuple instead. In the general case, this saves 3 bytes!

In Python 3.5+, this also works if we're appending to the end of a sequence, i.e. we can change `f(n-1,k,L+[b])` to `f(n-1,k,*T,b)`. The latter is a syntax error in earlier versions of Python though.

Answer (score 3):

To assign to a tuple, don't use parentheses. For example, `a=1,2,3` assigns `a` to the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`. `b=7,` assigns `b` to the tuple `(7,)`. This works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2 and 3 differences**

A [recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137040/fake-divisor-sum-polyglots) pushed me to search for differences in two major versions of Python. More precisely, code that returns different results in different versions. This might be helpful in other polyglot challenges.

1. Strings and bytes comparison

- Python 2: `'' == b''`
- Python 3: `'' != b''`

2. Rounding (Luis Mendo [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137062/66855))

- Python 2: `round(1*0.5) = 1.0`
- Python 3: `round(1*0.5) = 0`

3. Division (Jonathan Allan [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137119/66855))

- Python 2: `10/11 = 0`
- Python 3: `10/11 = 0.9090909090909091`

4. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

### List all substrings

You can generate the nonempty contiguous substrings of a string `s` with a recursive function (Python 3 for `[*s]`).

**40 bytes** [(TIO)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodgqWqs4NjEvJbo4VjtNozja0CpWE8yw0jWM1fxfbKuUmJScosRVUJSZV6IBlNDU/A8A)

```python
f=lambda s:[*s]and[s]+f(s[1:])+f(s[:-1])
```

This will repeat substrings multiple times even if each substring appears once. You can making this a set to remove duplicates. This won't run if `s` is a list instead of a string, but a tuple will work.

**40 bytes** [(TIO)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWqu4NjEvpbq4tiZNozja0CpWE8yw0jWM1fxfbKuUmJScosRVUJSZV6IBlNDU/A8A)

```python
f=lambda s:{*s}and{s}|f(s[1:])|f(s[:-1])
```

Or, you can do this to make a list where each substring appears one for each time it's present:

**46 bytes** [(TIO)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoVgnyVbX0Cpaqzg2MS8lujhWO02jONrQKlbHQBPMtEqK1fxfbKuUmJScosRVUJSZV6IBFNfU/A8A)

```python
f=lambda s,b=-1:[*s]and[s]+f(s[1:],0)+f(s[:b])
```

*Thanks for loopy walt for the `s[:b]` optimization.*

This can be used to sum over some expression `g` over all substrings, for instance to count nonempty substrings with some Boolean property `g`.

**48 bytes** [(TIO)](https://tio.run/##PcuxCoAgEADQva84blIqSNoE@5FwOBMrqCs6l77egqDtLe@883JwX0pyG@0hEkgTXGusDIjEEWYluk5KRmN90320wesiDilMEav5nxYJgY8MK4NAdV4rZ/UGrcsD)

```python
f=lambda s,b=-1:s>""and g(s)+f(s[1:],0)+f(s[:b])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Slicing tricks for hard-wired lists of strings

*Warning: Python is the language which worships readability above all else; so coding this way is a Mortal Sin.*

This sort of thing comes up a lot; such as [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171080/69880) where for a given digit in `0<=d<=9`, we can get the 7-bit segment `b` value as a hex string from the list

```
b=['7e','30','6d','79','33','5b','5f','70','7f','7b'][d]
```

If the length of such a list is more than just a few elements, you're usually better off at least using `split` because you can replace a bunch of `"','"`s with a single character `" "` as delimiter. E.g.:

```
b='7e 30 6d 79 33 5b 5f 70 7f 7b'.split()[d]
```

This can be used for almost any list of strings (possibly at a small additional cost using a delimiter such as `","`).

But if in addition, the strings we are selecting for all have the same length `k` (`k==2` in our example), then with the magic of Python slicing, we can write the above as:

```
b='7e306d79335b5f707f7b'[2*d:][:2]
```

which saves a lot of bytes because we don't need character delimiters at all. But in that case, usually even shorter would be:

```
b='7367355777e0d93bf0fb'[d::10]
```

Comment: A late answer, but I'm very curious why you would want to golf Python code to drive a 7-segment display. Hmm, perhaps to golf "human nerdsnipe" into the example, which is a noteworthy semantic addition given that it uses 0 additional bytes :D

Answer (score 3):

#### Unpacking in Python3

If you only need the first few values in the array

```
>>> a, b, *c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
[3, 4, 5]
```

Same applies to when you need last few values

```
>>> *a, b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
4
>>> c
5
```

Or even with the first few and last few

```
>>> a, *b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
>>> c
5
```

Comment: I was experimenting with this, and I found out you can also initialise an empty array if the number of values is one less than the number of variables, such as [`a,*b,c=1,2`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1FHK0kn2dZQx@h/QVFmXolGog6Qr/kfAA) or [`a,*b,c="ab"`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1FHK0kn2VYpMUnpf0FRZl6JRqIOUEDzPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Shortening `a%b==a` if `b` has a constant sign

For two expressions `a` and `b`, where each one results in an `int` (or `long` in Python 2) or `float`, you can replace these:

```
a%b==a
```

```
a==a%b
```

with these, if `b` is positive:

```
0<=a<b
```

```
b>a>=0
```

or these, if `b` is negative:

```
b<a<=0
```

```
0>=a>b
```

I'm presenting two expressions for each case because sometimes you may want to use one over the other to eliminate a space to separate expression `b` from an adjacent token. They both have the same precedence, so you're not usually going to need to surround the second expression with `()` if you don't need to do so to the first one.

This is useful if expression `a` is more than 1 byte long or `b` is negative, because it removes one occurrence of `a` from the expression. If \$a,b\$ are the lengths of expressions `a` and `b` respectively, and \$l\$ is the length of the original expression, the resulting expression will be \$l-a+1\$ bytes long. Note that this method is always going to be shorter than assigning expression `a` to a separate variable.

### Example

For example,

```
(a+b)%c==a+b
```

can be replaced with

```
0<=a+b<c
```

for a total saving of 4 bytes.

### Proof

Let's define the operator \$x\mathbin\%y\$ for \$x,y\in\mathbb Q\$.

[Every rational number \$a\$ can be represented as \$a=bq+r\$, where \$q\in\mathbb Z,0\le r<|b|\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). Therefore, we can define an operator \$a\mathbin\%b\$, where the result has the same sign as \$b\$:

$$a=bq+r,q\in\mathbb Z,0\le r<|b|\\a\mathbin\%b=\begin{cases}\begin{align}r\quad b>0\\-r\quad b<0\end{align}\end{cases}$$

This represents the `%` operator in Python, which calculates the remainder of the division of two numbers. `a % b` is the same as `abs(a) % b`, and the result has the same sign as the divisor, `b`. For the \$a\mathbin\%b\$ operator, this equality holds:

$$(a\pm b)\mathbin\%b=a\mathbin\%b$$

Proof:

$$a=bq+r\leftrightarrow a\pm b=bq+r\pm b=(bq\pm b)+r=b(q\pm1)+r$$

Moreover, for \$b>0\$, we have:

$$a\mathbin\%b=a\leftrightarrow r=a\leftrightarrow0\le a<b$$

Proof for \$r=a\leftarrow0\le a<b\$:

$$0\le a<b\leftrightarrow0\le bq+r<b\leftrightarrow bq=0\leftrightarrow a=r$$

Similarly, for \$b<0\$, we have \$b<a\le0\$.

Therefore, \$a\mathbin\%b=a\leftrightarrow\begin{cases}\begin{align}0\le a<b\quad b>0\\b<a\le0\quad b<0\end{align}\end{cases}\$, or, equivalently, \$(0\le a<b)\lor(b<a\le0)\$.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use `map` with list then cast it to list, use `*` instead of `list(...)`.

```python
new_a=list(map(f,a))
new_a=[*map(f,a)]     # -3 char
```

Moreover, you also can convert some iterable things to list with saving 3 characters:

```python
a=list("abc")
a=[*"abc"]
b=list(range(x,y))
b=[*range(x,y)]
```

Comment: the most concise way to do this is like this, saving one character::

`*a,=map(f,a)`

`*b,=range(x,y)`

Comment: sorry but I got "SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple" when I try it.

Comment: You must be forgetting the comma or possibly using Python 2. Here is a SO question about it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190992/understanding-x-lst

Answer (score 2):

Run your code through an space-remover, like this one:

```
#Pygolfer
a=raw_input()
for i in [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i]==" "]:
    try:b=a[:i]+a[i+1:];eval(b);a=b;print a
    except:pass
```

(This just tries to remove the spaces one by one, and try if the code still works. Please still do check your code manually.)

Manual things to do:
`print'string'` works.

`[str(i)for i in(1,2,3,4)]` works.

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate pseudo random numbers using hash.

`hash('V~')%10000`

Will print 2014.

Comment: Prints 9454 for me.

Comment: Python 2.7.2 always returns `2014`, but Python 3.4.0 returns more a more random number per session, like `6321`, `3744`, and `5566`.

Comment: Pretty similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python?page=2&tab=votes#comment21694_416).

Answer (score 2):

### Try a lambda expression

By default, [submissions may be functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/20260) and [functions may be anonymous](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/20260). A `lambda` expression is often the shortest framework for input/output. Compare:

```python
lambda s:s+s[::-1]
def f(s):return s+s[::-1]
s=input();print s+s[::-1]
```

(These concatenate a string with its reverse.)

The big limitation is that the body of a `lambda` must be a single expression, and so cannot contain assignments. For built-ins, you can do assignments like `e=enumerate` outside the function body or as an optional argument.

This doesn't work for expressions in terms of the inputs. But, note that using a `lambda` might still be worth repeating a long expression.

```python
lambda s:s.lower()+s.lower()[::-1]
def f(s):t=s.lower();return t+t[::-1]
```

The `lambda` is shorter even though we save a char in the named function by having it `print` rather than `return`. The break-even point for two uses is length 12.

However, if you have many assignments or complex structures like loops (that are hard to make recursive calls), you're probably be better off taking the hit and write a named function or program.

Answer (score 2):

## [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) in Python 2

Say you want to output `P` if `x>0`, `N` if `x<0`, and `Z` if `x==0`.

```python
"ZPN"[cmp(x,0)]
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/BsRE)

This function was [removed in Python 3.0.1](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons), although it [remained in Python 3.0 by mistake](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#comparisons).

Comment: Congratulations on the 100th answer to this question!

Answer (score 2):

## Abuse of `or` in `lambda`s

I'm surprised this isn't in here yet, but if you need a multi-statement `lambda`, `or` evaluates both of its operands, as opposed to `and` which doesn't evaluate the second one if the first one is not `True`. For instance, a contrived example, to print the characters in a string one by one with an interval:

```python
list(
    map(
        (lambda i: 
            sleep(.06) or print(i) or print(ord(i)) # all of these get executed
        ), 
        "compiling... "
    )
)
```

In this case it isn't shorter, but I've found it to be, sometimes.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69815/21487)

Comment: @Sp3000 *\*sighs\** I tried searching this question for `or`, `lambda`, `evaluation` etc but didn't see that

Comment: `lambda i:[sleep(.06),print(i),print(ord(i))]`

Answer (score 2):

## Omit needless spaces

Python tokens only need to separated by a space for

- A letter followed by a letter
- A letter followed by a digit

In all other cases, the space can be omitted (with a few exceptions). Here's a table.

```
  L D S
 +-----
L|s s n
D|n - n
S|n n n    

First token is row, second token is column
L: Letter
D: Digit
S: Symbol

s: space
n: no space
-: never happens (except multidigit numbers)
```

### Examples

**Letter followed by letter: Space**

```python
not b
for x in l:
lambda x:
def f(s):
x in b"abc"
```

**Letter followed by digit: Space**

```python
x or 3
while 2<x:
```

**Letter followed by symbol: No space**

```python
c<d
if~x:
x and-y
lambda(a,b):
print"yes"
return[x,y,z]
```

**Digit followed by letter: No space**

```python
x+1if x>=0else 2
0in l
```

(Some versions of Python 2 will fail on a digit followed by `else` or `or`.)

**Digit followed by digit: Never occurs**

Consecutive digits make a multidigit number. I am not aware of any situation where two digits would be separated by a space.

**Digit followed by symbol: No space**

```python
3<x
12+n
l=0,1,2
```

A space is needed for `1 .__add__` and other built-ins of integers, since otherwise the `1.` is parsed as a float.

**Symbol followed by letter: No space**

```python
~m
2876<<x&1
"()"in s
```

**Symbol followed by digit: No space**

```python
-1
x!=2
```

**Symbol followed by symbol: No space**

```python
x*(a+b)%~-y
t**=.5
{1:2,3:4}.get()
"% 10s"%"|"
```

Comment: In general, you can't have a letter after a digit if it confuses the lexer. A digit followed by `e` is expected to be a float literal, so something like `1else` wouldn't work for versions of python that support exponents in the literal. Similarly, as `0o` is the prefix of an octal literal, `o` can follow any digit but `0`. For the complete lexical rules, refer to https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: @xsot Do you know what versions of Python will parse this way? I remember a comment thread on this, but I can't find it.

Comment: I've always assumed these rules so I'm not sure which versions of python deviate from them. Possibly the older ones, if any.

Comment: @xsot It works on 2.7.10 but fails on Anachy's 2.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you're drawing, for colors, instead of typing:

`'#000'` for black you can just use `0` *(no apostrophes)*
`'#fff'` for white you can simply use `~0` *(no apostrophes)*
`'#f00'` for red you can just use `'red'`

---

Example of white being used with `~0`

```
from PIL.ImageDraw import*
i=Image.new('RGB',(25,18),'#d72828')
Draw(i).rectangle((1,1,23,16),'#0048e0',~0)
i.show()
```

Comment: `255` is even shorter than `'red'`. Some more ideas: `~255` is `'#0ff'` (cyan). `1<<7` is `#800000` (half-brightness red); similarly `1<<15` and `1<<23` are half-brightness green and blue.

Answer (score 2):

### Booleans are integers, too!

```py
assert True == 1
assert False == 0
assert 2 * True == 2
assert 3 * False == 0
assert (2>1)+(1<2) == 2
```

If you have a statement like `[a,a+x][c]` (where `c` is some boolean expression), you can do `a+x*c` instead and save a few bytes. Doing arithmetic with booleans can save you lots of bytes!

Answer (score 2):

Large hard coded numbers can be represented in larger bases, but there is a trade off. Higher bases only become worthwhile after a certain cutoff.

The only three bases you're likely to need to worry about are `10`, `16`, and `36`. These are the cutoffs:

```
1000000000000 (13 bytes)                            -> 0xe8d4a51000 (12 bytes)
0x10000000000000000000000000000000000000 (40 bytes) -> int("9gmd8o3gbbaz3m2ydgtgwn9qo6xog",36) (39 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Recursive functions that print

Functions [are allowed to print as programs do](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2457/20260). A recursive function that prints can be shorter than both a pure function and a pure program.

Compare these Python 2 submissions to make a list of iteratively floor-halving a number while it's positive, like `10 -> [10, 5, 2, 1]`.

```python
# 30 bytes: Program 
n=input()
while n:print n;n/=2

# 29 bytes: Function
f=lambda n:n*[0]and[n]+f(n/2)

# 27 bytes: Function that prints
def g(n):1/n;print n;g(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvJCsMgGAbv/1N41PTgcjT4JCEHi0uE5KsUS@nT2yzkNsMw9deWF0zvcAX107ig71LWyGDru6AxjJDOECW3@u0Z/B4wTGr2CBPmR@KQRhCFmFjmEFZLjPeZz9gvTVwrQRfng7tWfw)

The function that prints uses `1/n` to terminate with error on hitting `n=0` after having printing the desired numbers. This saves characters over the program's `while` and the pure function's base case, giving it the edge in byte count. Often, the termination can be shorter as part of the expression to print or the recursive call. It might even happen on its own for free, like terminating on an empty string when the first character is read.

The key property of our function here is that we're repeatedly applying an operation and listing the results at each step, in order. Additional variables can still be used this way by having them as optional inputs to the function that are passed in the recursive call. Moreover, because we're `def`'ing a function rather than writing a `lambda`, we can put statements such as variable assignments in its body.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The below makes sense only in the program is scored as characters, not as bytes.**

I haven't seen this, though somebody may have posted it somewhere.

I needed to have some long literal ASCII strings in the code so somehow shortening them (as characters, not bytes) would be beneficial. After some experiments I came up with what I call the "Chinese reencoding". I call it that way because ASCII characters mostly seem to be squashed in unicode code points that represent Chinese characters. You take an ASCII string S, encode it in bytes as ASCII, and then decode it in UTF16-BE, like that:

```
E=S.encode().decode('utf16-be')
```

The resulting string is half the length. It has to be big endian, as the reverse reencoding may not work - and on most systems the shorter 'utf16' is little endian. You also may need to add a character like space if the original string has odd length, but many times this is OK. Also, for non ASCII characters this does not save length, because they result in too big unicode code points that are represented in the liong form ("\uXXXX")

In you code, use the following:

```
[E].encode('utf16-be').decode()
```

in order to get the original longer string, where [E] is the literal shortened string. This costs 29 additional characters, so the original string has to be longer than 58, obviously.

One example - below is my 12 days of Christmas (it can be shortened additionally, but let's use that as an example):

```
for i in range(12):print('On the %s day of Christmas\nMy true love sent to me\n%s'%('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth Eleventh Twelfth'.split()[i],'\n'.join('Twelve Drummers Drumming,+Eleven Pipers Piping,+Ten Lords-a-Leaping,+Nine Ladies Dancing,+Eight Maids-a-Milking,+Seven Swans-a-Swimming,+Six Geese-a-Laying,+Five Gold Rings,+Four Calling Birds,+Three French Hens,+Two Turtle Doves, and+A Partridge in a Pear Tree.\n'.split('+')[11-i:])))
```

It's 477 characters long. Let's apply the "Chinese" trick to the two longer string:

```
r=lambda s:s.encode('utf-16be').decode();for i in range(12):print('On the %s day of Christmas\nMy true love sent to me\n%s'%(r('䙩牳琠卥捯湤⁔桩牤⁆潵牴栠䙩晴栠卩硴栠卥癥湴栠䕩杨瑨⁎楮瑨⁔敮瑨⁅汥癥湴栠呷敬晴栠').split()[i],'\n'.join(r('呷敬癥⁄牵浭敲猠䑲畭浩湧Ⱛ䕬敶敮⁐楰敲猠偩灩湧Ⱛ呥渠䱯牤猭愭䱥慰楮本⭎楮攠䱡摩敳⁄慮捩湧Ⱛ䕩杨琠䵡楤猭愭䵩汫楮本⭓敶敮⁓睡湳ⵡⵓ睩浭楮本⭓楸⁇敥獥ⵡⵌ慹楮本⭆楶攠䝯汤⁒楮杳Ⱛ䙯畲⁃慬汩湧⁂楲摳Ⱛ周牥攠䙲敮捨⁈敮猬⭔睯⁔畲瑬攠䑯癥猬\u2061湤⭁⁐慲瑲楤来\u2069渠愠健慲⁔牥攮ਠ').split('+')[11-i:])))
```

That's 362, including the lambda (it happens to be worth it, as it is used twice).

Now, all code is mostly ASCII characters, so you may have already guessed that you can use that with exec. There is higher overhead - 43 chars for "exec(''.encode('utf-16be').decode())" (in addition to the whole compressed program) and you may need to double escape some escaped characters in your literal strings (like '\n' in mine has to become '\n'). As a bonus you can always easily add that one space. The compressed porogram looks like:

```
exec("景爠椠楮\u2072慮来⠱㈩㩰物湴⠧佮⁴桥‥猠摡礠潦⁃桲楳瑭慳屮䵹⁴牵攠汯癥\u2073敮琠瑯\u206d敜渥猧┨❆楲獴⁓散潮搠周楲搠䙯畲瑨⁆楦瑨⁓楸瑨⁓敶敮瑨⁅楧桴栠乩湴栠呥湴栠䕬敶敮瑨⁔睥汦瑨✮獰汩琨⥛楝Ⱗ屮✮橯楮⠧呷敬癥⁄牵浭敲猠䑲畭浩湧Ⱛ䕬敶敮⁐楰敲猠偩灩湧Ⱛ呥渠䱯牤猭愭䱥慰楮本⭎楮攠䱡摩敳⁄慮捩湧Ⱛ䕩杨琠䵡楤猭愭䵩汫楮本⭓敶敮⁓睡湳ⵡⵓ睩浭楮本⭓楸⁇敥獥ⵡⵌ慹楮本⭆楶攠䝯汤⁒楮杳Ⱛ䙯畲⁃慬汩湧⁂楲摳Ⱛ周牥攠䙲敮捨⁈敮猬⭔睯⁔畲瑬攠䑯癥猬\u2061湤⭁⁐慲瑲楤来\u2069渠愠健慲⁔牥攮屮✮獰汩琨✫✩嬱ㄭ椺崩⤩".encode('utf-16be').decode())
```

and it's 299 characters long. You can see some high code points can always appear. I have not found a way to eliminate them, as the added handling code is not worth the benefit.

This is a cheap trick, in fact, but it can always be applied on top of your solution when the program is longish and there are no or few non-ASCII characters. Often you can devise a custom encoding that can stuff more than two ASCII chars in an unicode one, but it is specific for the task.

Comment: Most [tag:code-golf] questions are scored in bytes, not characters

Comment: Interesting, I don't do much and the ones that I have done were scored in characters - but it makes sense.

Comment: `exec(bytes('compressed code','u16')[2:])` is a shorter way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

To set lots of variables to the same thing use:

```
# x is a list of the names of the variables you want and y is
# the value you want all of them to have
exec(("%s="*len(x))%tuple(x)+str(y))
```

Comment: depending on the context `for c in x:locals()[c]=y` or `for c in x:globals()[c]=y` might also work.

Answer (score 2):

## Signum Function

Python doesn't have a nice signum built-in, even though its a very useful function for golfing. It takes a lot of bytes to use `math.copysign` or `numpy.sign` once you include the imports, and the latter doesn't even return ints, so you waste even more bytes if you need to use it in a list index, for example.

Here's a decent version you can use in that one answer where you really need integer signs multiple times:

```py
s=lambda x:(x>0)-(x<0)
```

If you don't need an integer, you can shave off one /. If you see any way to shorten it, please comment.

As per Jakque, in Python 2, you can use the cmp function.

Comment: `(x>0)-(x<0)` is much shorter

Comment: `cmp` (in pyhon 2 only) does also the trick  and is cheaper [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VQ9dUx1TTikuhoCgzr0QhU0dB3dZOXUchObdAI1PHQPP/fwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

To convert a 2D list to a 1D flat list, you can do `sum(2d_list,[])` instead of the long way of `import numpy;list=list.flatten()`, which requires to create a `numpy.array` at the start as well, which is way longer than the first one

Answer (score 2):

## Use Annotations to save on indentation

Hurry up before this feature goes away

If you have code like this:

```py
a:b = c
```

Is syntactically equivalent to

```py
a = c
__annotations["a"] = b
```

Note that if b is a expression, it can be evaluated. You can use this for side effects, for example consider this python quine:

```py
c:print(c%c)="c:print(c%%c)=%s"
```

In this case, this is the exact same length as

```py
c="c:print(c%%c)=%s"
print(c%%c)
```

However, in a indented context, it can save some bytes:

```py
if abcd:
   for defg in hijk:k:print(k(k))=eval(input())
```

Saves 5 bytes over:

```py
if abcd:
    for defg in hijk:
        k=eval(input())
        print(k(k))
```

Comment: You can just use semicolons, so this doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

If you have multidimensional array of numbers and for instance need to count all numbers greater than n.

First flatten the array, then apply filter function to match condition:

```
l=[[1,[8,4,7,1],3],[5,[7],3,9],[7,3,9,[[[8]]]]]
n=5
flatten=lambda l: sum(map(flatten,l),[]) if isinstance(l,list) else [l]
len(filter(lambda x:x>n,flatten(l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the all the indexes of a certain element in a list `l`, use

```python
filter(lambda x:l[x]==element,range(len(l)))
```

To find the next index after a certain index:

```python
l[:index].index(element)
```

To find the `n`th index:

```python
list(filter(lambda x:l[x]==element,range(len(l))))[n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rename **everything**

Here's a little Python 2 snippet that takes a module and a string, and renames every function in that module whose name is longer than 2 characters to a single character with the provided string prefixed. If you're writing a VERY LONG python program that uses many library or builtin functions (and if you manage to golf this snippet better than I have), it has the potential to save quite a few characters. On short programs or programs that use few functions, it will be useless. Since dir() sorts the names in a module, this will always provide the same names to the same functions, and you can use globals() to inspect which names it has given to which functions.

```
import string
def _(x,y):
 for c,f in zip(string.letters,[x.__dict__[q]for q in dir(x)if q in x.__dict__ and(len(q)>2)*type(x.__dict__[q]).__name__.find('eth')>0]):globals()[y+c]=f
```

You can use it to rename all the string and builtin functions like so:

```
_(str,'s')
_(__builtins__,'')
```

And then see what you actually ended up naming them like so:

```
for k in sorted(globals().keys(),key=lambda x:`len(x)`+x):print k,globals()[k]
```

If you only want to rename the builtin functions, it's best not to define the function and just use the body directly:

```
import string
b=__builtins__
for c,f in zip(string.letters,[b.__dict__[q]for q in dir(b)if(len(q)>2)*type(x.__dict__[q]).__name__.find('eth')>0]):globals()[c]=f
```

Comment: Golfed: https://tio.run/##RY67DoIwFIZneYputLbBW2TA8B4mxhzAFmksByg1aRdfHcui0z/8t28MrhvwuCxStQSoF0FguWdFQtrBkklYopH4DEDqhwPItFP9TKO/0S0xCunEdqftx4VRUctiDutexVyrUdJUuS5lxdMMTW1i6xb4o7MUd8d8m3Pk@ZndS3tBXh4WoADNWxuncQYQ6TVlyYoAsBLMg3VK0t9S9lIhiohSmrpvZE18Ua08nlXcs2K0Gl0si/85wH35Ag

Answer (score 1):

## Use a list if you have multiple choices based on int

Say for example you have some output that will be `1, 0, or -1` and you need a different output for each case. You could do something like this:

```
print('0'if x==0else('1'if x>0else'-1'))
```

However, the better way is to use `x` as an index to a list like so:

```
print(['0','1','-1'][x])
```

which is `16` bytes shorter.

Comment: for numbers that won't be used in concatenation: `print([0,1,-1][x])`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a list inside of a for loop.

For example:

```
L=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
queue = [None]*len(L)
for e, queue[e] in enumerate(L):
    print("adding", queue[e], "to processing queue")
```

This can also be helpful if you need to switch the object you're assigning to.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
a = Foo()
b = Foo()
for q, (lambda x: a if x%2==0 else b)(q).x in enumerate(range(10)):
    print(a.x, b.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pathlib from shorter files manipulations:

```
# get current dir, go up one dir, go down one dir, list all "py" files
# and get the whole file bytes

import os.path as p
import glob

d = p.join(p.dirname(p.abspath(__file__))), 'foo', '*.py')
for x in glob.glob(d):
    with open(x, 'rb') as f:
        do_stuff(f)
```

Becomes:

```
import pathlib as p

d = p.Path(__file__).absolute().parent / 'foo'
for f in d.glob('*.py'):
    do_stuff(f.read_bytes())
```

Answer (score 1):

## Checking the length of a list

```
Empty      : `a==[]` but just checking if it's non empty and swapping the if and the else can be shorter 
Non-Empty  : `a` (assuming it is in a situation where it will be interpreted as a boolean)
len(a)>i   : `a>a[:i]` if the list is non-empty
```

Comment: Additionally because ```[]``` is falsy, if want to check if a list is *not* empty, you can simply do ```if a:```.

Comment: The second one doesn't seem shorter? Although it can save a following space. But I think `1==len(a)` also works for that.

Comment: The second one gives an error on the empty list. Assuming nonempty, `a<a[:2]` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Fuse list comprehensions

You can write

```
[f(x)for x in l]+[g(x)for x in l]
```

As

```
sum([[f(x),g(x)]for x in l],[])
```

It gets even better with more comprehensions or if you have to take out more values

If you need to expand a list you can even turn `l+[f(x)for x in l]+[g(x)for x in l]` into `sum([[f(x),g(x)]for x in l],l)`

Comment: I don't think the two snippets return the same result. For example, `[i for i in range(10)]+[-i for i in range(10)]` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]`, while `sum([[i,-i]for i in range(10)],[])` returns `[0, 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9]`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `from lib import func as F`
2. `from lib import*;F=func`
3. `import lib;F=lib.func`

#2 is better than #1 except in rare cases where something in lib clobbers another name that's important to you.

#3 uses `lib` twice, winning with short library names.

Comment: `from lib import*;F=func` is shorter than `import lib;F=lib.func` for six letter names; it is always shorter than `from lib import func as F`.

Comment: @Dennis the `import*` trick is covered in a couple of tips farther up the list from here

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from comparing `import lib;F=lib.func` to `from lib import*;F=func` in this answer.

Comment: @Dennis you have a zillion rep on this site; you could edit it if you thought it would make the answer better

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a clever trick used [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189695/generate-brainfuck-for-the-numbers-1-255).

Instead of using the for loop to repeat multiple times, repeat exec multiple times.

```
p='+'
i=1
exec"print[p*i,i/9*p+'[>'+p*9+'<-]>'+i%9*p][i>20];i+=1;"*255
```

Compare this with

```
print"\n".join(">"+"+"*(i/16)+"[<"+"+"*16+">-]<"+"+"*(i%16)if i>31 else"+"*i for i in range(256))
```

Comment: There's already [an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64/) for this trick. Admittedly it has no examples.

Answer (score 1):

**Checking if a boolean value is false and an integer is a specific odd integer**

`~True` is `~1` is `-2` and `~False` is `~0` is `-1`

`-1&int` is always `int`

`-2&int` is always even

Therefore, despite operator order, `~bool&int==odd_int` works fine.

It's shorter than all of these equivalents:

`not bool and int==odd_int`

`-~bool and int==odd_int`

`-~bool&int==odd_int`

Comment: Though it's a niche situation, this does seem to be the shortest code for handling it. It's the same length to do `int<<bool==odd_int`, but starting with a number rather than `~` can require a space before it, say after `if`. If we know the integers are non-negative, then `int^int|bool<1` or `int^int<1>bool` works without needing oddness.

Answer (score 1):

Do a ternary operator when you can.

Factorial example:

```python
def f(x):return 1 if x==1 else x*f(x-1)
```

Comment: You can optimize it by doing:
`def f(x):return x==1&1or x*f(x-1) # 33 bytes` :)!

Comment: I didnt see it on the moment but you can even do: `def f(x):return x==1or x*f(x-1) # 31 bytes`

Answer (score 1):

## Use `**.5` instead of `math.sqrt()`

This is a very useful tip, especially if square roots are the base of your answer.

Instead of

```python
from math import*
x=sqrt(4)
```

which is 27 bytes, we can simply use

```python
x=4**0.5
```

Golfed, of course, it's

```python
x=4**.5
```

saving 20 bytes!

Note that this trick can be used for finding any root. Here is  a function that does this:

```python
lambda x,y:x**1/y
```

Answer (score 1):

##### (Destructively) Iterate any iterable in reverse

```
for x in s[::-1]:f(x)
```

can shorten to:

```
while s:f(s.pop())
```

when `s` is a `list` and destructive iteration is acceptable. But if you need to use the value multiple times, even with the walrus, this doesn't work so hot:

```
for x in s[::-1]:f(x);g(x)

while s:x=s.pop();f(x);g(x)  # Longer!
while s:f(x:=s.pop());g(x)   # Same length, and := precedence means it doesn't always work in larger expressions
```

And of course, `pop` calls don't work at all when `s` isn't already a `list`. In Python 3 though, you can use unpacking to do the `pop` work with fewer characters *and* it works on things that aren't `list`s (though they become a `list` after the first loop):

```
for x in s[::-1]:f(x);g(x)
while s:*s,x=s;f(x);g(x)
```

which shaves two characters, and (since it's already doing top-level statement work) doesn't have the issues with precedence in larger expressions that the walrus has.

Even for the single expression case, this can be useful:

```
for x in s[::-1]:f(x) # Works on any sequence
while s:f(s.pop())    # 3 characters shorter but works only on lists
while s:*s,x=s;f(x)   # Only 2 characters shorter, but works on *any* iterable
```

Since the minimal number of characters to convert iterables to a `list` is 2-3 (depending on use), paying one extra character to avoid the conversion can be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Integer ceiling division with no repeated terms and no extra parentheses fighting operator precedence

You have `n`, the numerator, and `d`, the denominator, or an expression, `a+b` as the denominator. Floor division is trivial:

```
n//d      # 4 characters. On Py2, n/d works, but Py2 is dead, move on
n//(a+b)  # 8 characters if denominator is expression with operator that is lower precedence
          # than division (or equal and same associativity), dumb parens
```

The naive approaches to ceiling division is one of:

```
math.ceil(n/d)      # 14 characters, and needs an import. Wrong if inputs large enough to hit
                    # C double integer representation limits (~53 bits)
math.ceil(n/(a+b))  # 18 characters; bad, but at least the denominator being an expression
                    # didn't make it proportionately worse

(n+d-1)//d          # 10 characters. No import needed, no C double precision limitations
                    # Repeats d twice though, so if d is a more complicated expression...
(n+a+b-1)//(a+b)    # 16 characters, and gets worse if d is more complicated or involves
                    # operators with precedence below +/-
```

As mentioned off-hand in [another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58404/70305), you can turn floor division into ceiling division with:

```
-(-n//d)        # 8 characters, shortest so far, and it only uses each term once, so...
-(-n//(a+b))    # 12 characters (whew, only paying for d expression once again)
```

but there is still one more optimization to be had. Unary negation is too high precedence, so we needed a second set of parentheses to separate negation of the numerator from the negation of the result of floor division (getting us ceil division as an end result). That's too much. But thankfully, subtraction is lower precedence than unary negation, so we can just subtract from zero, and get:

```
0--n//d      # 7 characters! Only three more than floor division!
0--n//(a+b)  # 11 characters, still only use d term once!
```

This is probably one of the only time Python code golfers are *glad* that Python doesn't offer a `--` decrement operator; since it doesn't exist, each `-` is separate, the first is a subtraction operand (relatively low precedence), the second unary negation (very high precedence), so no parentheses are needed; unary negation attaches *before* floor division, subtraction *after*, achieving ceiling division at the cost of one `0`, instead of open and close parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

1 or 0 can act as boolean operators in Python:

```python
func = lambda x:1 if x//2==x/2 else 0
while 1:
    if func(n):
         print('Hello')
    else:
         exit()
```

Which is 10 characters shorter than:

```python
func = lambda x:True if x//2==x/2 else False
while True:
    if func(n):
         print('Hello')
    else:
         exit()
```

Comment: Isn't this pointless in `func`? You could just have `func= lambda x:x//2-x/2` and reverse the consequences of the `if` (the subtraction will give 0 if they are the same, +/-1 if they are different). It might be better to point out that any python type that has a definition for `__bool__` or `__non_zero__` could be used instead of a boolean.

Comment: Here's a tip for golfing everywhere: don't return booleans with a conditional! `return True if condition else False` can *always* be simplified to `return condition`, or if the condition isn't a boolean and you need a boolean, use `return bool(condition)` or `return condition!=0` if it's a number.

Comment: @Cyoce This deserves to have many votes.

Comment: Also, the `while True` is unnecessary. It could be shortened to `while func(n):print('Hello')\nexit()` where `\n` is the new line character

Answer (score 0):

Not read all the answers but you can instead of

```
if x==3:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

use

```
print "yes" if x==3 else "no"
```

Comment: We already [have this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62/20260) in shorter form.

Comment: this is specific to print function as asked in the question I guess

Comment: `print"yneos"[x!=3::2]` based on this  [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/406/29577)

Comment: @xnor That isn't always applicable, for instance if using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert modules to lists

This will work for CPython (probably both 2 and 3), and lets you maybe shave a few bytes if you need to use a lot of different functions and classes with long names from the same module, but you aren't using any of them often enough to rename individually. You'll have to do some research first to figure out which magic numbers give you which functions. Example (rot13):

```
d=sorted
e=".__dict__.values()"
b=d(eval("__builtins__"+e))
s=d(eval("str"+e))
t=b[12]('string').maketrans
r=''.join(map(chr,range(65,91)))
w=r[13:]+r[:13]
l=t(r+s[4](r),w+s[4](w))
print s[28](b[53](),l)
```

Translated back to plain python, this is the same as:

```
t=__import__('string').maketrans
r=''.join(map(chr,range(65,91)))
w=r[13:]+r[:13]
l=t(r+r.lower(),w+w.lower())
print raw_input().translate(l)
```

which is obviously much shorter, but it should be clear how this methodology would eventually save bytes on much longer, more complicated programs that use more modules.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing can assign:

Converting BGR pixels array to RGB:

```
l = len(pixels)
for idx in range(0, l - 2, 3):
    pixels[idx + 2], pixels[idx] = pixels[idx], pixels[idx + 2]
```

Becomes:

```
l = len(pixels)
pixels[2:l:3], pixels[0:l:3] = pixels[0:l:3], pixels[2:l:3]
```

It's not just shorter. It's 5 times faster. Except on pypy, where the first version is 2x times faster :)

Comment: You don't really need to get the length, `pixels[2::3]` should work too

Answer (score 0):

Tricks with dicts:

```
# create a dict from iterable
d = {k: None for k in iterable}
# merge 2 dicts
d.merge(d1)
d.merge(d2)
# access a key, if it doesn't exist set a default value and return it
if 'foo' not in d:
    res = d['foo'] = 'bar'
    res = 'bar
else:
    res = d['foo']
```

Becomes:

```
d = {**dict.fromkeys(iterable), **d1, **d2}
res = d.setdefault('foo', 'bar')
```

Or if you need repeated access:

```
import collections as c
d = c.ChainMap(dict.fromkeys(iterable), d1, d2, {'foo': 'bar'})
res = d['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare 2 booleans to see if they are different, it's preferable to use `^` (XOR) rather than `!=` (it can save one byte)

Example with:
`a: bool` and `b: bool`

```py
if a!=b: # 8 bytes
```

```py
if a^b: # 7 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tip: this is a pretty useful (but rarely useable) alternative ternary operator which we use in Scratch: `*` and `+`. This uses the fact the booleans are equal to 0 and 1, and the rules of multiplying, but can only be used in limited situations.

For example, in string manipulations, you can use these. I used this in my code.golf submission:

```python
for i in range(1,101):print(f'{i}'*bool(i%3and i%5)+'Fizz'*(i%3==0)+'Buzz'*(i%5==0))
```

These can be sometimes long, so you can only use in limited situations. Note that string conversions may be necessary, as used in `f'{i}'`, thus making this impractical with multiple datatypes.

<s>This is also dangerous in recursive solutions, as all the conditions will be checked (so it doesn't terminate at a `True` value, thus recursing unnecessarily; the exact opposite of a short-circuit operator).</s>

So in factorials, this will fail to `RecursionError`:

```python
x=lambda n:n*(x(n-1)*(n!=1)+1*(n==1))
```

**EDIT:** It turns out that using this with `and` or `or` can actually solve the short-circuit problem mentioned above. See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264855/110681) as an example.

And for the factorial example (25 bytes):

```py
x=lambda n:n<2or n*x(n-1)
```

Comment: You can use `&` and `|` for the same purpose which have more convenient operator precidence

Answer (score 0):

#### Should you set variable?

<sub>This is perhaps already be posted but I could not find it with an explanation.</sub>

```python
gsetn = lambda n, k, c=3: n+c < (n-1) * k
gset = lambda n, s, c=3: gsetn(n, len(s), c)

gset(3,'range')       # == True
gsetn(3, 4)           # == True
```

The cost of using `f` of length `k` `n` times is `nk` and if it is set, the cost is `n+cost of setting`. So if `f` is used `n` times it is worth setting if
$$
n+c+k < n\cdot k\Leftrightarrow n+c < (n-1)\cdot k.
$$
Typically it costs `x=`+`k`+`\n`(or `;`) = 3 + `k` to set the variable.
Example:

```python
len('r,a,s=range,abs,sum;') == len('range')+len('abs')+len('sum')+3*3
```

But, it could be different:

```python
from math import factorial as f
```

Answer (score 0):

**Multiline Integer Inputs, works in Linux and Windows**

This may be much shorter for Python3 and inputs as integer

```
a,b,c=map(int,open(0))
```

For example expected input is:

```
23
45
56
```

The above golf code will assign respective integer values a=23, b=45, c=56

Answer (score 0):

If inverting result is fine:

```
a==123or b==123  # 15 bytes
123in[a,b]       # 10 bytes
a!=123!=b        #  9 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to use `list(map(lambda c: c.func(), iterable))`. This can be shortened to `list(map(<c's type>.func, iterable))`. For example: `list(map(lambda c:c.strip(), lines))` can be shortened to `list(map(str.strip, lines))`

Answer (score -1):

From what i learned:

1. Encode your long codes to base64 and use eval to run them: `eval(ENCODEFUNC(CODE))`. Something like zlib has half the size of b64 but there are even more efficient hash function that you can look up.
2. Use ternary operators and lambdas.
3. If the the task you trying to accomplish is a trivial thing then probably there is a builtin function for it somewhere.
4. Always look for a case for using list comprehensions and generators stuff.

Comment: How does the first one work? `a,b=1,2` and `a=1\nb=2` are both 7 bytes.

Comment: Never mind, that was wrong.

Comment: Base 64 is always 1.5 times as long as normal code